# The alphabet in programming languages

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity

Our task is to, for each letter of the (English) alphabet, write a program that prints the alphabet, in a language whose *name* starts with that letter.

**Input:** *none*

**Output:**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

*uppercase and trailing newline optional*

**Rules**:

- The scoring metric is the length of the programming language *name*, **plus** the length of the code.  Hence, C will be assessed a "penalty" of 1, while GolfScript will be assessed a penalty of 10.
- One language/implementation per answer.  Multiple answers are encouraged.
- If a programming language name's first letter is not an English letter, it should not be coerced into one.  It will be treated as a separate letter (meaning less competition).
- No answer will be accepted until every English letter has a solution.

---

Current rankings:

- [**A**​PL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83274): 5
- [**B**​NQ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259631/52210): 10
- [**C**​anvas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196625): 7
- [**D**​OS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206395): 13
- [**E**​SMin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271456/96266): 7
- [**F**​ig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254504/52210): ~4.646
- [**G**​s2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257297/52210): 4
- [**H**​usk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206362): 8
- [**I**​mplicit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271484/96266): 15
- [**J**​apt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196632): 6
- [**K**eg​](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195077): 6
- [**L**​y](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206363/92069): 13
- [**M**​ATL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271442/96266): 7
- [**N**​ibbles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259630/52210): 9.5
- [**O**​hm v2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271457/96266): 9
- [**P**​ip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196628/85052): 4
- [**Q**​uadR](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271458/96266): 9
- [**R**​ProgN](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271483/96266): 7
- [**S**​tax](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196627/85052): 6
- [**T**​hunno](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257190/114446): 8
- [**U**​iua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271422/96266): 10
- [**V**​](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196631/85052): 4
- [**W**​](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206514/92069): 4
- [**X**​Jam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215801): 10
- [**Y**​](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271419/52210): 30
- [**Z**​80Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171015): 16

Tell me if I'm missing anybody.

### Automatic leaderboard (experimental)

```js
var QUESTION_ID=2078;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&r.indexOf('non-competing')===-1&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],lang:/<a/.test(a[1])?jQuery(a[1]).text():a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var d=e.lang[0].toLowerCase(),a=s.lang[0].toLowerCase();return(d>a)-(d<a)||e.size-s.size});var s={},a=null,n="A";e.forEach(function(e){n=e.lang[0].toUpperCase(),a=e.size;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+" is for").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.lang,p=o[0].toUpperCase();s[p]=s[p]||{language:e.language,lang:e.lang,letter:p,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return(e.letter>s.letter)-(e.letter<s.letter)});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.language).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),jQuery("#languages").append(jQuery(i))}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*(?:<[^>]+>)?(?:[^]+?for )?((?:<a[^>]*?>)?(?:(?! [(=→-])[^\n,:])*[^\s,:])(?:[,:]| [(=→-]).*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px} /* font fix */ body {font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;} /* #language-list x-pos fix */ #answer-list {margin-right: 200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Winners by Letter</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <h2>Everything</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Language</td><td>Author</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Are we allowed to print junk to stderr?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Go nuts.  To answer your question, yes, printing junk to stderr is fine (as long as stdout is correct).

Comment: [Is it OK to print the alphabet IN BIG LETTERS?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83316/53917)

Comment: Funge is distinct from Befunge. Surely my pedanticism will be rewarded on a site dedicated to feats of it!

Comment: Is anyone going to update the rankings?

Comment: Is `*0*5AB1E` the same as `*o*sabie` :P?

Comment: Does "x86" work as the name for x86 machine code?  Out of all ISAs, x86 is clearly recognizable as the name of this one.  It's not a language that people regularly program in *directly*; usually we generate it from assembly language (or higher level languages) so "x86 machine code" is as much a description as a name.  A 9-byte x86 function was straightforward, so that would give a score of 12.  Or 11 if we use "IA" (Intel Architecture) as the name of the language, but xtal 35 has much more room for improvement so that's a more useful answer to reducing the total sum length across all letters.

Comment: Is ```,,,``` the same as (```*C*ommata```) :P?

Comment: Is length in characters or bytes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## K is for [K](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 12 characters -> Score: 13

```
`0:_ci97+!26
```

Comment: Surely you can adapt one of your solutions to A+, right?

Comment: Setting up A+ is a little funky. I've done it before but I don't really feel like it. (Owl, newLISP and zshell were all turnkey.)

Comment: i assume that's k2 or k3. in k4/q, you can do it in 7 chars with `1 .Q.a;`.

Comment: you don't need `\`0:` or `1@` in codegolf

Answer (score 26):

## P is (actually) for [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) - 57 codels

Large version (codel size = 6)

[image: p is for piet - big]

Small version (codel size = 1)

[image: p is for piet - small]

Tested with Erik's piet interpreter [`npiet`](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/) and developed with [Piet Creator](https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator/wiki).

**Edit**: Here is a "trace" version (generated with `npiet -tpf`) so you can see how it works.

Execution starts in the top left and goes around the border clockwise. The top edge and right edge are setup (calculating the value of `a` (97) takes quite a few codels). The loop starts on the bottom edge and goes to the left edge. When the value of `z` is reached the program turns right into the cross section under the first `P` and terminates.

[image]

Click the image to enlarge and see details

Comment: Oooh, Piet is always a nice one. And you don't happen to have a working Windows binary of Piet Creator lying around, do you? (I was too lazy to hunt all dependencies and prerequisites just to play around a bit again.)

Comment: And aren't that actually 400 codels and 57 *coding* codels? (I don't think we had a consensus how to count Piet here, though)

Comment: @Joey I'll see if I can cook up a build of Piet Creator for windows. It's been awhile since I tested it there. You're right about the codels. If I was to lay the program out in a line it would be 57 codels (give or take a few), the version above is more eye friendly (like whitespace in other langs). Perhaps Piet submissions should have both minimal and eye-catching sources. We better decide, because I'm planning many more Piet answers :)

Comment: Well, you could open a question on [meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/) to ask for clarification how Piet code should be handled :-). I would have submitted Piet solutions too, long ago. Except pietdev was quite buggy and for Piet Creator I needed Qt and a few other things just to build it ;-). And just using a bitmap editor is quite ... cumbersome ...

Comment: @Joey Piet Creator still needs several important enhancements to be truly awesome, hopefully I can add those soon. I end up using mainly Piet Creator, and then use Paint or the GIMP to move blocks of color around. Pietdev was my main inspiration for PC. Getting some feedback on PC would be great, I'll get on that windows build ASAP.

Comment: @Joey The github site now has a windows build from today. Let me know if you find any bugs (I'm sure you will). My email is in the README. https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator/downloads

Answer (score 17):

### P is for Perl, 10 characters -> Score: 14

```
print a..z
```

Comment: What about `say a..z`?

Answer (score 15):

### P is for Python 2, 29 chars -> Score: 35

Every few years I come here with an update. See below.

Also I'm proposing the addition of range expressions to Python [over here](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-204-range-literals-getting-closure/25026) with [demo code here](https://github.com/jbvsmo/cpython/pull/1). That would allow us to make an even more compact answer.

### Mar 2023: 29 chars

I realize the question says the output can be uppercase which allows us to shave off another char. It is quite ridiculous I didn't see that before.

```
print bytearray(range(65,91))
```

### Nov 2019: 30 chars

I did it, after 8 years I realized there is a shorter way in python 2!

```
print bytearray(range(97,123))
```

Previous code that was as big as trivial print:

### Jul 2011: 33 chars

```
print'%c'*26%tuple(range(97,123))

print'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Edit: Check out the breakthrough with Python 3 where I also found a solution smaller than trivial print: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195165/2212

Comment: This is the same length as `print'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`...

Answer (score 14):

### Y is for [Yoix](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Eyoix/latest/index.html), 44 characters → Score: 48

```
int x;for(;++x<27;)yoix.stdio.putchar(96+x);
```

Answer (score 13):

### W is for Whitespace, 72 characters -> Score: 82

[image]

```
[Sp][Sp][Sp][Tab][Tab][Sp][Sp][Sp][Sp][Tab][LF][LF][Sp][Sp][Tab][Tab][LF][Sp][LF][Sp][Tab][LF][Sp][Sp][Sp][Sp][Sp][Tab][LF][Tab][Sp][Sp][Sp][Sp][LF][Sp][Sp][Sp][Sp][Tab][Tab][Tab][Tab][Sp][Tab][Tab][LF][Tab][Sp][Sp][Tab][LF][Tab][Sp][Sp][Sp][LF][LF][Sp][LF][Tab][Tab][LF][LF][Sp][Sp][Sp][Sp][LF][LF][LF][LF]
```

I spent ages getting this stupid thing to work last night and then found that whitespace doesn't show as code here! Then, while I was sulking, my Internet connection died. So, I'm posting it now just so I didn't waste an hour of my life last night getting it to work.

Comment: I would have thought that it was obvious from the now-deleted comment along with my solution that I've never written any Whitespace before. Apparently not.

Comment: @Mego Any chance we can have my name taken off this since I had nothing at all to do with it?

Answer (score 11):

### A is for APL,  <s>14</s>  11 chars/bytes* → score 14

```
⎕UCS 96+⍳26
```

This works at least in Dyalog and [Nars2000](http://www.nars2000.org/).

---

<sup>* APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Comment: `⎕a` works in [APLX](http://www.dyalog.com/aplx.htm).

Comment: *uppercase and trailing newline optional* so `⎕A` works.

Answer (score 10):

### G is for Golfscript, 8 characters -> Score: 18

```
123,97>+
```

Answer (score 10):

### R is for R, 19 → Score: 20

```
cat(letters,sep="")
```

Comment: Alternatively (20 characters): cat(letters,sep="")

Comment: Is not `letters` good enough? I don't see the spec specifying the output must be a contiguous string. Sure, the example given is in that form, but the 'trailing newline is optional'?

Comment: @Gaffi: I believe I held other languages to the same standard in this thread, namely, the output must be "abc...xyz" exactly, with no intervening characters).  I suppose I could change the rule and win my own contest, but that wouldn't be very fun.

Answer (score 7):

### R is for Ruby, 13 characters -> Score: 17

A Ruby 1.9 solution [Matma Rex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/979/matma-rex) came up with:

```
print *?a..?z
```

My original Ruby 1.8 solution (15 characters -> Score: 19):

```
$><<[*'a'..'z']
```

Comment: This one doesn't match the criteria? Output contains additional characters. Also, if it's OK, it'd be `$><<[*?a..?z]` for Ruby 1.9 (shaving off 2 chars).

Comment: Shortest correct version I can conceive is `print *?a..?z`. It's the same length and the one I suggested above. We can't use `$><<` because `<<` has some weird precedence rules and everything blows up. We can't use `p` or `puts` instead of `print` since they print every letter on separate line.

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that this is for Ruby 1.8. In Ruby 1.8, `Array#to_s` is the same as `Array#join`, so it'll just print the alphabet with no extra characters. But your 1.9 solution is indeed shorter.

Comment: Output is: http://codepad.org/atGFGVuQ

Comment: @George: Your output is from Ruby 1.8 (which can be verified here: http://codepad.org/pvyqzaPP). As the post mentions, this is a solution for Ruby 1.9.

Comment: @Vent: Sorry... I really know nothing about Ruby, so please forgive me :)

Answer (score 7):

## D is for dc, 17 characters → Score: 19

```
97[dP1+dBD>x]dsxx
```

Comment: outputs "ab" and quits in dc version 1.06.95

Comment: @Wossname `echo '97[dP1+dBD>x]dsxx' | dc` does work in dc version 1.07.1

Answer (score 7):

### F is for Fish (><>), 19 chars -> Score: 23

Because it's a damn beautiful language!

```
30"`"1+::o&p&"y"(?;
```

Comment: Isn't this answer scored 22 because `<>>` is only three characters long, not four. Is there a reason you used the longer name in the score.

Comment: @ppperry Well the language name can't both start with an F and be `<><`.

Comment: The name of the language is `><>`, not `<><`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work- it just prints `a`. https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39hAKUHJUNvKKl@tQE2pUknD3vr/fwA

Answer (score 6):

### S is for Scala, 16 chars => score 21

```
'a'to'z'mkString
```

<strike>18 chars => score 23</strike>

```
'a'to'z'mkString""
```

22 chars => score 27

```
('a'to'z')map(print _)
```

Answer (score 6):

### C is for C, <s>36</s> 35 characters → Score: 36

```
main(a){for(;putchar(a+++64)-90;);}
```

Comment: You can drop 2 characters by assuming a (argc) equals one rather than having to initialize it.

Comment: But this doesn't even compile...

Comment: Best I could get to compile was 59, or 42 without the include:

#include<stdio.h>
main(){for(int a=27;--a;)putchar(96+a);}

Comment: Daniel, it works with MSVC 10 here.

Answer (score 6):

## O is for [Owl](http://digilander.libero.it/tonibinhome/owl/), 11 characters -> Score: 14

```
a[%)1+%z>]!
```

Answer (score 6):

### P is for Python 2, 42 characters → Score: 48

```
import string
print string.ascii_lowercase
```

Comment: `print 'abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Comment: `print'abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Answer (score 6):

## B is for Befunge → 18 characters

```
"a"::,1+10p"y"`#@_
```

Comment: Can be done in [16 characters](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30opUUnbSqlKKUHZIV7HUPv/fwA "Befunge-93 – Try It Online"), for a score of 23.

Answer (score 5):

### P is for PowerShell, 15 characters → Score: 25

```
-join('a'..'z')
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure whether to make this W or P.

Comment: Technically it's W, since the correct name of the language (and product) is *Windows PowerShell*. Yes, it bugs me too.

Comment: [The language is now just PowerShell, with the products being Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), so this now has a score of 32.

Comment: @dorukayhan: When using PowerShell Core we can also shorten it to `-join('a'..'z')` which results in 25.

Answer (score 5):

### L is for Logo, 26 characters → Score: 30

```
for[i 97 122][type char i]
```

Answer (score 5):

### P is for Python 2, 41 characters → Score: 47

```
print''.join(chr(i+97)for i in range(26))
```

Answer (score 4):

### B is for [bc](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bc/) - 2 + 28 = 30

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 4):

## J is for J, 14 characters -> Score: 15

```
echo u:97+i.26
```

Comment: Why bother with `echo`? `u:97+i.26` is a complete J program.

Comment: Because that has no output when run as a script (for me, anyway).

Answer (score 4):

### B is for Bash: 4 + 16 = 20

```
printf %s {a..z}
```

or 15 with just:

```
echo {a..z}
```

if output of the form `a b c ...` is allowed (as seen in many other answers).

Comment: I don't think so. Linefeed is optional, output is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Answer (score 4):

### T is for Thue, 35 characters → Score: 39

```
0::=~abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
::=
0
```

Answer (score 4):

### M for Matlab, 13 chars, Score 19

```
disp('a':'z')
```

<strike>M for Matlab, 18 chars, Score 24</strike>

```
disp(char(97:122))
```

Comment: I don't have matlab at hand but I think you need `disp(..)` to prevent this outputting `ans =  `.

Comment: Correct, changed in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

### A is for AppleScript, 41 -> Score: 52

```
display alert"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Comment: I know this is a _long_ time since posting, but you can use `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, since the return value is output to the results pane.

Answer (score 4):

## B is for BrainF***, 38 + 9 = 47

```
++++[>++++++<-]>[->+>++++<<]>++[->+.<]
```

Can be reduced to **31+9 = 40**, if cells wrap around at 256:

```
++[>+>++<<+++++]>----->[<.+>++]
```

Answer (score 3):

### I is for [Inform 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inform#Inform_6), 41 + 6 = 47

```
[Main i;for(i=26:i--:)print(char)'z'-i;];
```

Answer (score 3):

### U is for [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/programs/unlambda/) - 8 + 79 = 87

```````````````````````````
``````````````````````````.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o.p.q.r.s.t.u.v.w.x.y.zr
```````````````````````````

Answer (score 3):

### Q is for QBasic, 29 characters → Score: 35

```
?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Untested, but programming is like riding a bike, right?

Comment: You can get injured while riding a bike.  I dare you to drop that space before the quotation mark.

Comment: Nah, that would look too much like "optimized" BASIC programs...

Comment: You can use `?` instead of `print` ...

Comment: Feel free to edit, I haven't programmed in BASIC for more than a decade.

Comment: Done :-). Tested now, even.

Comment: You can get fewer points by using QBX. Score 31

Comment: You can drop the last quotation mark - QBasic will fix that for you!

Answer (score 3):

### H is for Haskell, 21 characters → Score: 28

```
main=putStr['a'..'z']
```

Answer (score 3):

### S is for Scheme, 37 -> Score: 43

```
(display"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

Answer (score 3):

**L is for LUA: 3 + 40 = 43**

```
repeat n=1+(n or 96)print(("%c"):format(n))until(n>122)
```

-> 55

```
repeat n=1+(n or 96)print(string.char(n))until(n>122)
```

-> 53

```
for i=97,122 do print(string.char(i))end
```

-> 40

Comment: Please keep the code blocks clean, so user scripts like [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) which insert code block sizes in the document can show correct values. I mean, please post separate solutions in separate code blocks and specify the code length outside the code block.

Comment: Thanks. This way is much easier to spot out count mistakes: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qezQZ.png Seems you included in both cases the final newline character in the count. That is unnecessary.

Comment: @manatwork do you happen to have that userscript lying around anywhere...? the dl link is borked :/

Comment: Sorry @cat, I used to mention that one in the comments, as I consider it the official one, but I use a [simple one](http://manatwork.bitbucket.org/blog/2015-11-30-code-size/) written for my own need.

Comment: You can remove 2 bytes (and obfuscate) by using `("").char` in place of `string.char`.

Answer (score 3):

## G is for [GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 30 characters -> score 32

```
Strchr(vectorsmall(26,i,96+i))
```

If I stole the 36-character C code I could submit it as a score-40 submission for PARI -- though maybe at that point I'd be required to `#include <pari/pari.h>` at the painful cost of an additional 23 characters.

I'm too embarrassed to submit

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

which would be printed in gp.

Answer (score 3):

## I is for [International Phonetic Esoteric Language (IPEL)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 19 bytes + 4 characters = 23 score

```
{97}{q}0ɑbesχue1søɒ
```

Score <s>can be</s> is 24 <s>if</s> since IPEL is acceptable.

### Explanation

```
{97}{q}0ɑbesχue1søɒ
{97}                (push ord of "a")
    {q}0            (push loop bounds: 0 to 26. Q == 26 in base36)
        ɑ           (start loop)
         besχu      (print chr[65+index])
              e1sø  (increment index)
                  ɒ (end loop)
```

---

## I is for [International Phonetic Esoteric Language (IPEL)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 20 bytes + <s>40</s> 4 characters = <s>60</s> 24 score

```
{97}{26}0ɑbesχue1søɒ
```

Comment: "IPEL" is acceptable in my opinion.  I'm only disappointed that the numeric literals keep the entire script from having a standard pronunciation.

Comment: hmm maybe i should allow letters in multi-digits and make it base 36 if it has a letter

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 26 characters -> Score: 29

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2):

### P is for PostScript, 29 chars → Score: 39

```
(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)=
```

Answer (score 2):

### B, 45 -> Score: 46

```
main(){auto i;i=95;while(i++<122)putchar(i);}
```

Answer (score 2):

### m4, 26 characters -> Score: 28

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

(Hey, shinh lists it as a supported language)

Answer (score 2):

## Xtal, 31 characters -> Score: 35

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".p;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for filling in `X` with something interesting!  I guess you mean Gnu Xtal System (found with a Google search), but I'm not sure.  Could you add a link?

Comment: It's actually Xtal as used in golf.shinh.org: http://code.google.com/p/xtal-language/ , you can see some post-mortems at http://golf.shinh.org/l.rb?xtal

Answer (score 2):

### [E](http://erights.org/), 28 characters → Score: 29

```
for x in 0..25{print('a'+x)}
```

Answer (score 2):

## N is for newLISP, 35 characters -> Score: 42

```
(print"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Z is for zsh, 31 characters -> Score: 38

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2):

### L#, 28 characters → Score: 30

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 2):

## F is for [False](http://strlen.com/false-language), 17 characters -> Score: 22

```
97[$123\>][$,1+]#
```

Answer (score 2):

### A is for awk: 37 characters -> score 40

```
BEGIN{for(i=96;i++<122;)printf"%c",i}
```

Answer (score 2):

### U is for [Unicon](http://unicon.sourceforge.net/), 50 + 6 = 56

```
procedure main();every writes(char(97 to 122));end
```

Answer (score 2):

### c,34 characaters -> score : 35

```
main(a){for(;a++<27;putch(95+a));}
```

Comment: `putch` isn't in standard C, and isn't present on my system.  Thus, I'm not going to add this to the rankings, at least not under C.  Arguably, you could change the language name to "VC" (for (Microsoft) Visual C) and put it under V ;-)

Comment: @Joey: Shouldn't *any* C example be classified under the compiler name, then?

Comment: @Joey, @avinashse: I went ahead and reluctantly added this to the scoreboard.

Comment: talking about vc++... if you set the entry point to f and the subsystem to console, you get a breathtaking 1 + 30 = 31
`f(a){26-a&&f(putch(a+97)-96);}` :)

Answer (score 2):

### G is for Groovy, 25 -> Score: 31

```
('a'..'z').each{print it}
```

Answer (score 2):

## V is for VBA - 43 (40+3) or 32 (29+3)

(formatted to run in the immediate window)

**40 chars**

```vb
For b=65 To 90:c=c & Chr(b):Next:Print c
```

And shorter, but no thinking involved:

**29 chars**

```vb
?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Comment: You can crunch the loop method to 27+3 by using ? for print and ; to make it not insert a newline.  for i=65to 90:?chr(i);:next

Answer (score 2):

**Forth, 29 + 5 Score: 34**

```
: a 123 97 do i emit loop ; a
```

**Previous (Forth, 48 + 5 Score: 53 (unclean score = 48))**

```
: a 97 begin dup emit 1 + dup 123 = until drop ;
```

This is the clean version.

```
: a 97 begin dup emit 1 + dup 123 = until ;
```

The second one leaves stuff on the stack.

```
a 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  ok
```

Comment: Or even : b ." abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ; at 36 characters

Comment: If uppercase output were permitted then you could drop a character with `91 65 do ...` I have to say you should probably include the word `a` (+2 chars) at the end of your line for these to be "programs", otherwise nothing is actually executed or printed. :( I do like golfing in Forth but it often carries that penalty!

Comment: @DarrenStone OK, I've changed it - I do wonder about that though as I see, for example C source code in code golf that would also not print anything without being compiled and executed at a command line. I'm just starting out at code golf and trying to remember Forth from my youth. It is fun.

Comment: Yeah, it sucks that control structures (`IF`, `LOOP`, etc.) can't be used in interpreted mode, only in a word definition. Shaving down your string constant idea, the following would be a program and requires no word definition/execution penalty.  `." abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`  Unfortunately, it's 30 chars! Happy Forthing!

Answer (score 2):

**C++, 32 + 3penalty = 35**

I could not find C++. So this is my option for it:

```
char a=96;while(a++<122)cout<<a;
```

the output is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

PS. It's my first golf, pls comment if i did something wrong

Answer (score 2):

## A is for APL, 9 characters → Score: 12

```
17↓43↑⎕av
```

Take the first 43 characters from `⎕av`, then drop the first 17 of those.

(Tested in Dyalog APL)

Comment: Are you sure this works in a version of Dyalog that predates the question?

Comment: I checked via archive.org what the current version was in February, 2011, which was 12.1. Checking the manual for that shows that `⎕av` was a feature, so it should work.

Comment: Sounds good; I'd appreciate if you test it though.

Comment: Couldn't get hold of a 12.1 myself, but I asked the developers of Dyalog, and they tried it and confirmed that it worked the same all the way back to 10.0, which should be well before the question was posted :) https://twitter.com/dyalogapl/status/695184773266960384

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 60 -> 69

```
+++++[>+++++<-]>+>++++++++[>+++[>++++<-]<-]>>+<<<[>>>.+<<<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwSi7cCUjW6snTaECROEyAAlQHJ22jY2NtF2dnZ6IIZu7P//AA)

-2 bytes thanks to Dust

Comment: Consider doing the addition at the beginning (the first 3 chars) later in the code. You could golf 2 bytes with `+++++[>+++++<-]>+>++++++++[>+++[>++++<-]<-]>>+<<<[>>>.+<<<-]`.

Answer (score 2):

## A is for APL, 2 → 5

```
⎕a
```

Works on MicroAPL's [APLX](http://microapl.com/apl_help/ch_020_070_020.htm).

Answer (score 2):

### V is for Vim, 9+3 → Score: 12

```
:h<_<CR>LY<C-^>P
```

The screen must be exactly 66 characters wide, and 8 lines high. You can check this with `tput cols` and `tput lines`.

The program should be executed with:

```
echo>file.txt && /bin/vim -u NONE $'+normal :h<_\xALYZQP' '+wq' file.txt && cat file.txt
```

As discussed in [this vim scoring meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8995/how-should-vim-answers-be-scored)

Comment: Since a trailing newline is optional, you might as well drop the `V` to save a byte, and replace the `p` by `P`

Answer (score 2):

## L is for Lua, 49 bytes → Score: 52

Previous answer for Lua had each letter printed on a new line. All on one line:

```
s=""for i=97,122 do s=s..("").char(i)end print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FZJKS2/SCHT1tJcx9DISCElX6HYtlhPT0NJSVMvOSOxSCNTMzUvRaGgKDOvRKNY8/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## B is for Brainfuck, 42 Bytes + 9 = Score 51

```
+++++++++[>+++++++++++>+++<<-]>-->-[-<.+>]
```

### Ungolfed and commented

```
+++++++++[>+++++++++++>+++<<-]  Leaves the tape with the values 99 and 27.
>--                             Subtracts 2 from 99 to make 97, the ASCII Code for an "a".
>-                              Subtracts 1 from 27 to make 26, the number of letters in the alphabet.
[-<.+>]                         Outputs the letter, adds 1 and decrements from the number of letters remaining.
                                When no letters are remaining, the loop Exits.
```

Answer (score 2):

## B is for [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>32</s> 31 + 9 = 40

-1 byte thanks to Jo King

```
-[>++>+<<-----]>----->+[<.+>--]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pOW9tO28ZGFwRi7cCUnXa0jZ42kB37/z8A)

`-[>++>+<<-----]>` is derived from the [initialization part for 51](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#51) and generates the following layout: `102|51`. The next part `>----->+` changes this to `97|52` where `52` is double the amount of letters in the alphabet and `97` is the charcode of `a`. The final loop `[<.+>--]` prints a letter and increments the charcode and decrements the counter twice.

Answer (score 2):

## B is for [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes → Score: 11

```
Ạẉ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuBQ93df7/DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## C is for [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 15 bytes, Score -> 20

```
uo)U"z`"-?@./;/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/780XzNUqSpBSdfeQU/fWv//fwA)

Cubified

```
    u o
    ) U
" z ` " - ? @ .
/ ; / . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=dW8pVSJ6YCItP0AuLzsv&input=Cg==&speed=20)

Answer (score 2):

## X is for x86, 9 bytes + 3 -> score 12

(or "x86 machine code" for 9 + 16 = 25)

```
b0 61 aa 40 3c 7a 76 fa  c3
```

This is a function, callable with `void alpha(char edi[26])`, like the x86-64 System V calling convention but in 32-bit mode.  Or 16-bit mode (where `40` decodes as `inc ax`, otherwise the same).

**The question says "program" that "prints"**, and this is neither of those things.  I'm not sure this should count.  Making a DOS .com executable out of this would take a few extra bytes, or the `.text` section of a Linux executable, including print and exit system calls.  But there are several other answers (like some C++ ones) that are merely snippets that wouldn't even compile without `#include<iostream>` and `int main(){`.

I'm just going to follow modern codegolf defaults for I/O methods ([Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)) which include returning a string in the caller's buffer.

---

An x86-64 version would cost 1 extra byte for `inc al` or `inc eax`, and 3 extra characters in the language name.  I could call it x64 but that implies Windows where the standard calling convention doesn't use RDI.  But that's irrelevant, this is an asm / machine-code answer which doesn't care about being called from other languages.  So anyway, I could say "x64" for a 10 + 3 = 13 version, but I hate that name because it goes with using "x86" to mean specifically 32-bit, instead of the whole ISA.

Ungolfed:

```
                machine code     NASM/FASM source
     1                         alpha:
     2 00000000 B061               mov  al, 'a'
     3                         .loop:               ; do {
     4 00000002 AA                 stosb              ; *edi++ = al
     5 00000003 40                 inc  eax           ; more compact than inc al
     6 00000004 3C7A               cmp  al, 'z'
     7 00000006 76FA               jbe  .loop       ; }while(al<='z')
     8 00000008 C3                 ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLTsMwELz7K@aAVJDSqimIolYc4YQ48AORnWxaI8eOYoe6/fngOGkQbS35MbuzOzvm1lIl1HFeclt1XWmaiju8fbyDPOWt40IRHhnjqt7zDUNYlfkBuEow4zO2UMbUQ9w6Y0V8SZ0DxH0EeVWP9NMsBr4FAbEuwoYcGFtYeaINCoE7zBHVOtKuOSKzjjeObXfKCK7OcLgG4X7Vrd0D6fKMsYWmg5KaJoptRTjJ1glWz1M0ugEVMulTUzjnSmGYg11yuU/wNMlkn1/ZoZGOLmki0NKJVhaX@dxHyTEv2vJqpkBYrc8NFGm89jj8rmoLqXdwe7pyKbUL59K//H1FLI8j3qdJL5T0zR5u@kr/@SIv3cTyphlthX1Dj3W/) with a FASM `_start` caller.

---

**Justification**: "x86 machine code" is as much a description as a name.  Machine code is something you can program in and can be considered a family of languages.  But those languages don't usually have names other than the ISA.  I'd usually say "x86 32-bit machine code" when posting an answer like this, but that's just to make it clear the answer is the machine code, not the asm source text in the same listing.

Out of all ISAs, x86 is clearly recognizable as the name of this one.  It's not a language that people regularly program in *directly*; usually we generate it from assembly language (or higher level languages).

"IA" (Intel Architecture) or "IA-32" are other common names for the ISA, so I could argue for a score of 11 in the letter "I".  (But the only "x" answer is xtal at 35, so posting this as x86 is a more useful answer for reducing the total sum length across all letters.

Of course "x86" can be considered ambiguous between the machine code and assembly language.  And without context it's not obviously a programming language because it's better known as the name of an ISA.

Comment: I like this answer, it's a great intro to x86 assembly.  I can't believe how few bytes each instruction takes.

Comment: @JoeyAdams: There are special-case short forms for the accumulator (EAX / AX / AL), and instructions with implicit operands like `stosb`.  In "normal" 32-bit code most instructions are 2 to 4 bytes long, or longer with larger addressing modes or SIMD opcodes...  And 64-bit code needs a REX prefix on many instructions, making the avg instruction length more like 4 in compiler output.  See [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981)  I just updated the source version with comments for the benefit of people who don't know x86 asm, since you mentioned it :P

Comment: But yes, ISAs with variable-length instructions optimize for the most common cases.  Original 8086's main bottleneck was code-fetch from memory so they put some care into that design.  It's evolved over time into an ugly Frankenstein's monster though, with much lack of long-term thinking about ISA extensions. :(  See Agner Fog's 2009 blog post, [Stop the instruction set war](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25)

Answer (score 2):

## K is for [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 3 + 3 bytes - > 6

```
azɧ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/serk8v//AQ)

It *seems* that the rule disallowing newer languages to be posted has been removed. Let me know if this is somehow invalid.

Answer (score 2):

## T is for [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 19 bytes → 19+10 = 29

```
,5,D@"*i.jC>"dj>F+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X8dUx8VBSStTL8vZTikly85NW///fwA)

Ungolfed:

```
     , 
    5 , 
   D @ " 
  * i . j 
 C > " d j 
> F + /
```

The process here is,

- Push 65
- Push 27
- `j` is a conditional NorthWest IP switch; it changes to NW if the top value of the stack is not 0. This means we have the equivalent of looping from 26 to 0 (because we decrement prior to entering the loop)
- Decrement → `j` → Swap top 2 stack values → Print, don't pop → Increment → Swap → Repeat

This turns out to be 1 byte shorter with capital letters than lower case due to 97 being prime.

Answer (score 2):

### P is for Python 3, 32 chars -> Score: 38

```
print('%c'*26%(*range(97,123),))
```

Using uppercase letters, this can be made shorter

```
print('%c'*26%(*range(65,91),))
```

This is based in [my 2011 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3091/2212) which is before Python 3.5 added starred tuple unpacking, making it smaller that that one....

EXCEPT for Python 2 also got a smaller version today which is unbeatable :)

Unless Python adds range expressions to the language, which I am proposing [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-204-range-literals-getting-closure/25026)

Answer (score 2):

## M is for [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 20 characters - Score: 24

```
[!43W8WM;1M!93WA?.%]
```

Explanation:

```
[        start of loop
!        duplicate top of stack
43W8W    push 96 to stack (4*3*8)
M        add 96 to number below
;        output top of stack as ASCII char
1M       add 1 to top of stack
!        duplicate top of stack
93W      push 27 to stack (9*3)
A        Difference of top two stack values
?.       is equal to zero, then terminate program
%        pop top of stack
]        end of loop
```

Answer (score 2):

#### **X is for x86-16 MS-DOS machine code - 16 bytes**

This is hexdump from `.COM` file :

```
00000000  b4 02 b9 1a 00 b7 61 8a  d7 cd 21 fe c7 e2 f8 cd  |......a...!.....|
00000010  20                                                | |
00000011
```

Code I wrote :

```
.model small
.code
org 100h

start:

    mov ah, 02h
    mov cx, 26 
    mov bh, 97

.loop:
    mov dl, bh
    int 21h
    inc bh
    loop .loop
    int 20h

end start
```

I use DOSBOX to run this proram

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### B is for Batch File, 31 characters → Score: 41

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ada, 92 characters -> Score: 95

```
with ada.text_io;use ada.text_io;procedure a is begin put("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");end;
```

Answer (score 1):

### F is for F#, 36 characters -> Score: 38

```
printf("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl - 31 + 3 = 34

```
puts abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: My shortest iterative is longer, 45 :`time {puts [format %c [expr [incr i]+96]]} 26`

Answer (score 1):

## Wake, 33 bytes, score 37

```
all: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

### [E](http://erights.org/), 26 characters → Score: 27

```
for x in'a'..'z'{print(x)}
```

*This is based off [Joey's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/the-alphabet-in-programming-languages/2102#2102).*

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 36 + 6 = 42

```
print''.join(map(chr,range(97,123)))
```

Not the shortest...

Answer (score 1):

### P is for PHP - 33 characters - Score: 36

```
echo implode("",range("a", "z"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**V for VBA: 60**

```
Sub VforVBA()
For i=1 To 26: a=a & Chr(64+i): Next: Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you remove any of the spaces between the tokens?  E.g. `For i=1To26:a=a&Chr(64+i):Next:Debug.Print a`

Comment: @JoeyAdams edited as suggest

Comment: Did you test this?  Is "Fori" treated as "For i"?

Comment: @joeyAdams Yea you're correct, indeed the 1To26 and other parts won't work as well.  I have changed it back to origin answer

Comment: @Alex I think you can remove some spaces (`i = 1`, `: a = a & Chr(64 + i)`, `: Next: Debug`)

Answer (score 1):

### C++: 32+3 = 35

```
char c=96;while(c++<122)cout<<c;
```

Comment: I almost want to score this as 32, given that your code contains "c++".  Alas, I didn't put this in the original rules.

Comment: @JoeyAdams You're right, I corrected it :)

Answer (score 1):

### C is for Clojure - (39 or 53) + 7 = 46 or 60

No, it doesn't stand for C. In Clojure, all functions form closures, so I would argue this is a complete answer, in 39 bytes.

```clojure
(doseq[c(range 97 123)](print(char c)))
```

But if you really want it with the main function, 53 bytes.

```clojure
(defn -main[](doseq[c(range 97 123)](print(char c))))
```

But, this isn't a Clojuric way to solve this problem. Let's try something simpler (could be golfed for 4 bytes).

```clojure
(print (apply str (map char (range 97 123))))
```

Much better, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

## U is for [Unix Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), 21 Characters → Score: 31

```
echo {a..z}|tr -d " "
```

Comment: I think `printf '%s' {a..z}` would shave off some chars

Answer (score 1):

## V is for VBScript, 40 Characters → Score: 48

```
for i=97 to 122:a=a+chr(i):next:MsgBox a
```

Answer (score 1):

## P is, in fact, for PHP - 23 chars / 27 score

```
<?=join('',range(a,z));
```

Answer (score 1):

## N is for [Nu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_(programming_language)), 35 Characters → Score: 37

```
(puts 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Answer (score 1):

## N is for Nim, 31 → Score: 34

```
for x in'a'..'z':stdout.write x
```

Answer (score 1):

### S is for [SMBF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Self-modifying_Brainfuck), 10 chars -> Score: 14

SMBF stands for Self-modifying Brainf***, and both names are used interchangeably. The original interpreters were named `smbf.c` and `smbf.rb`.

`\x1a` is a hex literal (a single non-printable ASCII character) for the decimal number 26.

```
<[-<.+>]a\x1a
```

The `\x1a` is used as a loop counter. `a` is printed and incremented each time.

Answer (score 1):

## B is for Bash, 11 -> <s>15</s> 24

```
echo {a..z}
```

```
echo {a..z}|tr -d \ 
                   ^
                 space
```

Comment: Already [posted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2108) by [Eelvex](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46/eelvex), but sadly it is not valid, because not produces the exact required output.

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way. Keep trying, keep posting. If you found this independently, you're very good. In the future, try answering less popular challenges. :-)

Comment: ETHproductions, done.

Answer (score 1):

## Mouse, 26 + 5 = 31

```
97a:(a.123<^a.&DUP !'1+a:)
```

Which outputs:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Note the lame way would be:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Which gets printed implicitly immediately (as string literals do, unfortunately), but it's 28 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## J is for Java - score: 84 characters + 4 = 88

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){for(char c=65;c<91;System.out.print(c++));}}
```

This prints `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` instead of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. If it's disallowed, one can simply set `c` to 97 (`a`) and loop until it reaches 123 (`{`) at the cost of one extra byte:

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){for(char c=97;c<123;System.out.print(c++));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### S is for [seed7](http://seed7.sourceforge.net/), <s>137</s> <s>114</s> 78 characters → Score: 83

```
const proc: main is func begin writeln("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");end func;
```

Answer (score 1):

## F is for Funge → 19 chars + 5 = 24

```
'\`#;1+::,"@9"+\`#@_;
```

Something that makes this **unique is that it doesn't contain a single letter of the alphabet!** Hence why I didn't shorten it by replacing `"@9"+` with `'y`. I'll take the points hit for it.

Try it with my interpreter here: [BefungeSharp](https://github.com/tngreene/BefungeSharp).

Answer (score 1):

### D is for [D2](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/d2), 2 + 6 = 8

```
!a[.+]
```

`!a` expand to 10 `+`, setting the current cell to `10` (`a` in base 36), and `[.+]` print the current cell as a base 36 string and increment the cell. Since the maximum value a cell can hold is 35, at 36 the cell is zeroed and the loop stop.

Answer (score 1):

## S is for Swift, 76 characters -> Score: 81

```
var s=""
for i in 97...122{s.append((Character(UnicodeScalar(i))))}
print(s)
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just print a string containing the alphabet?

Comment: Of course, but that just wouldn't be as fun

Comment: `my_string` could be reduced to one letter.

Comment: good call @pppery

Comment: You should update the bytecount after golfing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 26 bytes (score 27)

```
paste(letters,collapse="")
```

Output:

```
[1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

## S is for SmileBASIC, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
FOR I=65TO 90?CHR$(I);:NEXT
```

Comment: I do not believe you have properly read the scoring rules for this challenge. Your score is the length of your code plus the length of the language name.

Comment: Fixed, sorry. (padding)

Comment: You can save 2 characters by adding 65 to the start/end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## Y is for [Yorick](http://dhmunro.github.io/yorick-doc/), 30+6 bytes → 36

```
system,"echo {a..z}|tr -d ' '"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Z is for Zsh, 21+3 → 24 bytes

```
echo {a..z}|tr -d ' '
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX6E6UU@vqrampEhBN0VBXUH9/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## R is for [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 17 bytes Score -> 18

```r
intToUtf8(97:122)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzOvJCQ/tCTNQsPS3MrQyEjz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

### M is for M, 20 characters → Score: 21

```
let s={"a".."z"}in s
```

([M language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/power-query-m-reference))

Answer (score 1):

## Z is for [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 9 bytes + 7 = 16

```
00000000: 3e61 061a ff3c 10fc 76                   >a...<..v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMU80MFQzMDBMV0tKMkxUMDdKSFczNFDCBXaKenp6Nnl7Z//8A)

According to the [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20071223030922/http://www.mokehehe.com:80/z80golf/), Z80Golf code golf machine was created (at least) in December 2007.

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  ld a, 97  ; the char to print
  ld b, 26  ; loop count
loop:
  rst $38   ; 1-byte alias for putchar
  inc a
  djnz loop ; decrement b and jump to `loop` if nonzero
  halt      ; end program
```

Answer (score 1):

## Z is for Zsh, 19 characters -> Score: 22

19 character solution thanks to @GammaFunction.

```
<<<${(j::):-{a..z}}
```

Another 18 character solution using Perl.

```
perl -eprint\ a..z
```

Comment: Not sure whether that would qualify for Zsh, it's more "Zsh+perl" (which would have a much larger penalty). You can get a pure Zsh answer in 19 characters, though: `<<<${(j::):-{a..z}}`

Answer (score 1):

## I is for [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 31 characters -> Score: 33

```
for($,65,90,$asCharacter print)
```

Answer (score 1):

## F is for Fish, 16 bytes; score 20

```
"a"r:o1+:"{"=?;r
```

Answer (score 1):

## F is for [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 26 + 5 = 31

```forth
'{ 'a [do] [i] emit [loop]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//q1crqCcqRKfkxypEZ8YqpOZmlihE5@TnF8T@/w8A)

Two improvements over [the submission by leancz 6 years ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15960/78410):

- An ASCII char prefixed with a quote gives the ASCII value of that char. So `'{` saves a byte over `123`. `'a` is just for consistency.
- The looping words including `do` and `loop` can't be used in interpreted mode, but `gforth` provides interpreted versions surrounded with brackets like `[do]` and `[loop]`. If a function uses three or less such words, using interpreted mode saves some bytes, as illustrated below.

```forth
\ using compiled mode
: a '{ 'a do i emit loop ; a
\ using interpreted mode
'{ 'a [do] [i] emit [loop]
```

Answer (score 1):

## P is for [Pyth](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/), 1 character -> Score: 5

```
G
```

[Try it out!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=G&debug=0)

That's it - just 1 letter. This is how it works:

- The variable `G` is by default initialised to `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in this language.
- By default, the value returned by a program is printed out to the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 26 bytes, score: 29

Glad to hear that newer languages are allowed.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v8/MSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyisur/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes, score: 7

Jelly has a built-in.

```
Øa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjMT//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte, score: 5

Pyth has a shorter built-in than Jelly.

```
G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3/3/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 1 byte, score: 4

```
z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/6v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 3 bytes, score: 4

```
¬az
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//9CaxKr//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 58 bytes

The iteration method

```
System.printAll((97..122).map{|i|String.fromCodePoint(i)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@gKDOvxDEnR0PD0lxPz9DISFMvN7GguiazJrgEKJWul1aUn@ucn5IakA9UqJGpWav5/z8A)

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 42 bytes

The boring method

```
System.print("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@gKDOvREMpMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyiskpJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 33 bytes

I thought I could beat Brachylog... never mind.

```
"a">:,1+:"{"-#v_@
   ^          <
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/XylRyc5Kx1DbSqlaSVe5LN6BS0FBIU4BDmz@/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes → Score: 8

```
…"ab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDMqXEpP//AQ)

Comment: `…"ab` saves a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 11 bytes -> Score: 13

```
'Rrp['`+o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/19dKqioIFo9QTs/9v9/AA)

### Explanation

```
'          Push 26
  R          0-range
   r         reverse stack
    p        Pop 0
     ['`+o] Output the whole stack, added by 97
```

Comment: This less interesting, since it's brute force, but shorter https://tio.run/##y6n8/189Ub0qSC3//38A

which is this:   'a'zR&o

Answer (score 1):

## F is for [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 17 bytes, score: 20

```
&65>&26(-1<$c+1>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fzczUTs3ITEPX0EYlWdvQTvP/fwA)

Ties the Fish answer.

Answer (score 1):

## DOS, x86, 10 bytes + 3 = 13

This answer is fundamentally the same as [Peter Cordes' x86](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194014), but uses DOS for I/O and as the "framework" of sorts to be able to "print[s] the alphabet" per the challenge description.

One could attempt to make the case that since this uses DOS API for said I/O that it one-step higher level than just x86.  After all, DOS is an operating system, programming API, interpreter and framework all rolled into one, right?  Also most every submission here eventually gets compiled down to machine code eventually to run, so aren't we really considering the submission to be the highest level required to produce the desired output?

Okay, feel free to call this rationalization baloney.  It's not shorter than Peter's earlier x86 so just thought I'd throw in another take, competing or not! :)

**Binary:**

```
00000000: b061 cd29 403c 7a7e f9c3                 .a.)@<z~..
```

**Listing:**

```
B0 61       MOV  AL, 'a'        ; start at 'a'
    CLOOP:
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write AL to console
40          INC  AX             ; increment letter
3C 7A       CMP  AL, 'z'        ; is <= 'z'?
7E F9       JLE  CLOOP          ; if so, keep looping
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS
```

[image]

*And yes "DOS" can be considered a generic term for other different non-IBM PC Disk Operating Systems.  However [Wikipedia's entry for "DOS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) specifically refers  to IBM DOS and describes DOS as "a common shorthand for disk-based operating systems on IBM PC compatibles".*

Answer (score 1):

### [Ni](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ni), 13 bytes, score: 15

```
#61>#1a{<!+>}
```

[Try (the snippet) online!](https://tio.run/##jZVRk5owEMff@RQ57ANUoXqtPjhqO3NPfbi3vlmnEyEc6WDihOB549ivbjchKHokHqOQkP39dxeyS1Hh0ynhKUFz5Pcmo0VvhA@zh/7i6HtewRNcoKxiiaScoZzsHymTQSlF6CE4BJGVYEhyVm3WRKiFARpNQo@w1MBFhY36cmluPcNkMh5/HZs5HaCkoNs1xyKFIawOB@p3ON4GkBR4sw3YAG0oQ3DG@zoOmiGGZvquzAnT99TBQAuMUARnmcd4XQasJkhREk0ttMF7CqT6KIC1qIUaFpJrZc9a2Z4j/VtBoDsTHejVke90Xs9hFyHoSy6DW4L2Rw6mIFkHErkQnKaGSJZ0BVCgr1ygYQgZj7qYslrbmcjCENnkb6Bdl1lSECyuxYdddryS20r@ZOd0efwqqCStSOzYU372ceZgq1L2Eidq6aLRKUIZaFzHCDKCYHiS0/UbiHViCd@@NVSzvdVLapx1MVtcarmWqwt7hqII/coJ0nVVSixkCaUpyNRbrZqSKp/4ZkOYBIEMw173MqBVsnPYHD1Nply7qYEd/OdacaretrIcaPtLgXHZkr0qGFjVPHSQT75eapV9M4pj5Ndl4atx00uuXKrNrq/fwlADoX92Yiq2cbRwOzLVZMVnbrwuLCvdd9O6xqxw5IZ1sVnh3h0Yqu4Dj/fx7uP97vZT720rPXfTZpdb8c93nNc9w4rHbrzVSqwSDx@RqNuKVeOHW8N0FSu@dOOvOS3IVSP@B60TitoqeHALqgbxR3WHtqZDLriTXvY@OGVv1Qt9ZdrMVlezo9sX9ESr7BeDtjuiFBW52Juv@Q33m3WAdSttKPU3/ZbsdVAcp/V3JTDxhR5IqkUtBYMgVOjp9B8)

### Explanation

```
#61           Set Current as 'a'
   >          Move the pointer right
    #1a       Set current as 26
       {      Repeat 26 times:
        <         Move left
         !        Print the letter
          +       Increment the letter
           >      Move right
            }     (Automatically decrement counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w/), 3 bytes (score: 4)

Near built-in solution, intended to beat Wake.

```
'zk
```

### Explanation

```
'z   Push the character z
  k  Generate a downwards character range for that character.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Q is for [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 26 bytes, Score: 31

```apl
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/z8xKTklNS09IzMrOyc3L7@gsKi4pLSsvKKy6v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## V for [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes, score 2+5=7

```
ka
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=ka&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Dunno someone has posted this already

Answer (score 1):

## K is for [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes -> Score: 18

```
`c$97+!26
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLSFaxNNdWNDIDAAuPAgw=)

Bruh.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes + 3 = 4.646

```
ca
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJjYSIsIiJd)

Answer (score 1):

## N is for [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes (5 nibbles) + 7 = score 9.5

```
|@\$l
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWS2scYlRyIGyoEEwKAA)

```
|           # filter
 @          # printable ASCII characters:
  \         #   is the character 
   $        #   of each of them
    l       #   a lowercase letter?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Y is for [Y](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Y), score 30 (29 bytes)

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"p
```

[Try it online](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Y/) by copy-pasting the code above and clicking the `timeout run` button.

**Explanation:**

```python
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  # Push all characters between the "-quotes to the stack
                            p # Print the entire stack to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

## M is for [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes, Score 7

```
2Y2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yjS6P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Q is for [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 8 bytes, score: 13

```apl
819⌶⎕A⋄⍵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/9/C0PJRz7ZHfVMdH3W3POrd@v8/AA)

### Explanation

Lowercase (`819⌶` - "BIg" without a boolean is un-BIg) the uppercase alphabet (`⎕A`). The `⋄` avoids any additional output, and the `⍵` means this line should be run as code, rather than as a regex transformation.

---

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 4 bytes, score: 9

I didn't realise it was allowed to use uppercase alphabet, which simplifies this greatly...

```apl
⎕A⋄⍵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6//9R31THR90tj3q3/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

### vimscript

What does output mean?

Assuming output to the current vim buffer is ok:

```
:norm aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Otherwise, output to stdout:

```
:!echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 26 + 3 = 29

```
<?=implode('',range(a,z));
```

Answer (score 0):

**AWK,33+3(Penalty)**

```
END{for(;i<26;)printf"%c",97+i++}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 34 + 10 = 44

```
alert('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Comment: `alert(8337503854730415241050377135811259267835n.toString(36))` ;)

Answer (score 0):

## H is for HTML -> 4+31

```
<HTML/>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

*ps: browser will interpret the missing end tag*

Comment: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` is *far better* at 30.

Answer (score 0):

## T is for TI-BASIC, 27 + 8 = 35

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Can be run from command line, as a standalone program, or called as a function.

Answer (score 0):

### **S is for Scala, Score: 40**

```
print("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket, 46 bytes (score 52)

```
(for((i 26))(display(integer->char(+ i 97))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## B is for Bash, 25 bytes

```
echo {a..z}|tr -d ' '
```

(21 bytes of code plus 4 for the language name)

Answer (score 0):

### R is for REXX, 15 characters → Score: 19

```
say xrange(a,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

## U is for [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 36 bytes → Score: 42

```
1 PRINT "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fUCEgyNMvREEpMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyiskrp/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## F is for FALSE, 15 bytes +5 = 20

```
97[$'{-][$,1+]#
```

Doesn't use any letters!

### Explanation:

```
97 {push 97 (ASCII for 'a')}
  [ {function start}
   $'{- {subtract '{' from the current letter}
       ] {function end}
        [ {function start}
         $, {print the current letter}
           1+ {add 1}
             ] {function end}
              # {while loop. Run the second function while the first doesn't return 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

## V is for VBA, 28 + 3 = 31

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` to the VBE immediate window.

The two solutions below are of equal length and produce the same output

```vb
For i=97To 122:?Chr(i);:Next
```

Or

```vb
?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

## U is for [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 30 + 6 = 36

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

```
0?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwF4pMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyiskrp/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## S is for SmileBASIC, 27 bytes + 10 = 37

```
FOR I=65TO 90?CHR$(I);
NEXT
```

Prints the alphabet in uppercase. (I'm not sure whether this is allowed, but other people are doing it so...)

Just 1 character shorter than the (even more) boring answer:

```
?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

## I is for [ICI](http://atrn.org/ici/), 37+3 bytes → 40

```
printf("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

## I is for [Io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_%28programming_language%29), 35+2 bytes → 37

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"println
```

Answer (score 0):

## C is for Common Lisp, Score 35 + 11 => 46

```
(princ"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/1@joCgzL1kpMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyiskpJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## P is for [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 15 bytes+10 = 25

```powershell
-join('a'..'z')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQz1RXU9PvUpd8/9/AA)

Uses the character range feature added in 6.0 to improve upon past answers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 1 byte, score: 7

```
ｚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v///d5Z//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes, score: 11

Learnt this language just for solving this problem.

```
'{,'a,-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X71aRz1RR/f/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes, score: 6

Also, Stax has a built-in.

```
Va
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JrPj/Pyzx/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes, score: 6

```
₵a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//1HTViAJAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte, score: 9

```
▄
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtJb//wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes, score: 6

```
;C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39r5/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte, score: 7

```
A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8f9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/) (with `-S`), 37 characters, score: 44

```
std.repeat("%c",26)%std.range(97,122)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jsonnet -Se 'std.repeat("%c",26)%std.range(97,122)'
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

## C is for [C](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9ZI1OzOi2/SCPT1sjMOtNas6C0JDkjsUjD0lA3U1dX07r2f25iZp6GZnWyBogDAA), 34 bytes + 1 = 35

```c
c(i){for(i=26;i;)putchar(91-i--);}
```

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9ZI1OzOi2/SCPT1szUuqC0JDkjEcjR1ta0sTSw1rSu/Z@bmJmnoVmtkaxhoAniAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## X is for [XJam](https://github.com/Eiim/XJam), 6 + 4 = 10

```
'[,65>
```

What is XJam, you may ask? It's a language I started creating earlier this year and gave up before doing anything really interesting. It technically does fulfill its design criteria though, which is to be a version of CJam which adapts to the informal specification in the xkcd comic [X](https://xkcd.com/2309/). It accomplishes this by using a custom charset where Unicode characters representing variations on the letter X fill the top 32 slots in  what's otherwise standard 7-bit ASCII. Those characters are then the only ones which can be used as variables. It also happens to be perfect for this challenge, beating the [previous x answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194014/96155) by two. (Sorry Peter Cordes, that x86 answer was great!)

Credit where it's due, the code is taken from Lynn's answer on a different question [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67387/96155). It doesn't use variables so it ports over perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Eso2D](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Eso2D), 15 bytes + 5 = 20

```
2v
,>#1~5
@#,5<
```

Eso2D is a language starting with E that has a relatively short name and an instruction set very good for string construction that I found on the esolang wiki. This could probably be improved further, but it's more than enough for a new best E.

Explanation:

```
2v        Increment the accumulator by 97 and move down to the second row
,>#1~5    Loop (from wrapping): print num to char, add 50, check if > 170, decrement by 49 otherwise.
@#,5<     Once it hits 171, decrement by 49 and print one last time before stopping.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 11 bytes, score 14

```bash
&65(91$c+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fzcxUw9JQJVnbUPP/fwA)

```bash
&65(91$c+1)

&65           # Set current cell to 'A'
   (91    )   # While current cell != 'Z'+1
      $c      # Print ASCII of current cell 
        +1    # Increment current cell
```

Beats the previous Foo answer by not using another cell.

Answer (score 0):

## P is for [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 4 bytes

```
ɫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5Or//wE)

Gotta love builtins

Answer (score 0):

## T is for [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), 2 + 6 = 8

```
Az
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLHKsgDCgfJg4A)

Answer (score 0):

## G is for [gs2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 1 + 3 = 4 bytes

```
à
```

Uses the [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding.

Hexdump:

`85`

Answer (score 0):

## B is for [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 7 bytes + 3 = score 10

```
'a'+↕26
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=J2EnK+KGlTI2)

```
    ↕26     # range from 0 to 25
   +        # add to 
'a'         # character 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

## U is for Uiua, 6 bytes, Score 10

```
+@A⇡26
```

First Non-Vyxal answer

Answer (score 0):

## E is for ESMin, 2 Bytes, Score 2+5 = 7

```
ᶛ
```

[Try it online, firefox only](https://bennyboy.tech/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=&code=%E1%B6%9B)

Answer (score 0):

## O is for [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 3 bytes, 6+3 = 9

```
αa,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9zGRJ3//wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 1 byte, 6+1=7

```
a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P@/8/8f9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](https://github.com/aaronryank/Implicit), 7 bytes, 7+8=15

```
26¡"é64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/9/I7NBCpcMrzUz@/wcA)

```
26¡"é64­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
26¡      # ‎⁡range [1,26]
   "     # ‎⁢convert entire stack to ascii character
    é64  # ‎⁣increment each character by 64
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).