# Produce the word 'codegolf' without using any of its characters in code

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

You need to produce the word **codegolf**

---

#### **Rules:**

1. ***None*** of the characters of the word `codegolf` (i.e. 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'o', 'l' and 'f') in either case can exist anywhere in the code.
2. Case of the word must be one of three:

   - All Upcase (`CODEGOLF`)
   - All Downcase (`codegolf`)
   - Capitalized (`Codegolf`)
3. You only need to produce it somehow so there can be other characters in the output as well. For example, `21§HCodegolf092` is an acceptable result.
4. The shortest code (counting in bytes) to do so in any language wins.

---

I guess it will be less trickier in some languages than others (Brainfuck, Javascript, etc.)

Comment: I feel like we've had basically this challenge before, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because "print X without X" is a type of challenge that's been done to death and people are tired of it. So, it's not your question but the site's history, which I can't blame you for not knowing.

Comment: @xnor - Thanks for explaining, I'm new to this stack site. :P

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world). Also [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/print-the-alphabet-without-using-each-vowel)

Comment: Sigh... This is impossible in java. If `c` or `l` were allowed I might be able to do it. I would also need `o` or `f`.

Comment: In J, ` {8#<a.` *should* work. However, the interpreter spots the memory problem that this would cause, and throws an error.

Comment: @TheBestOne You can use unicode representation in Java, assuming none of them have `edfg` in the character code. This will undoubtedly make it much longer, though.

Comment: @TheNumberOne Boilerplate: `class A{public static void main(){System.out.printf("CODEGOLF")}}` I think you can do `\uxxxx` in Java instead of those. And nope, `u` is not disallowed.

Answer (score 12):

### Bash(works if there are no other files matching `/bin/?at`), 14

```
/bin/?at /*/u*
```

This expands to `cat <files>`, where the files include /dev/urandom. Because of the infinite monkey theorem, this will eventually output "codegolf".

Comment: Well, I almost surely upvoted you.

Comment: It got stuck on `/dev/ptmx` on my system.

Comment: @user23013 Sorry, didn't think of that. Will edit.

Comment: And `/*/?at` worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

## PHP, 8 bytes

```
CODEGOLF
```

Does not contain 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', etc.

(You *might* want to ban their uppercase versions as well.)

Comment: Hahahaha, you know what I meant. Let me rephrase the question.

Answer (score 9):

## C - lots of characters

Without `include`, `define`, `char`, `printf`, `return` and lots of other useful things, it's a real challenge to try to do this in C.

I thought of outputting upside down letters, i.e. ɟloƃǝpoɔ, but the l and o are the same.

So here's the best I can do, which many people might remember as being very much like their first C assignment.

```
int main()
{
    puts("                   @                       @     @@ ");
    puts("                   @                       @    @   ");
    puts("                   @                       @    @   ");
    puts("  @@@    @@@    @@@@   @@@    @@@@   @@@   @  @@@@@ ");
    puts(" @   @  @   @  @   @  @   @  @   @  @   @  @    @   ");
    puts(" @      @   @  @   @  @@@@@  @   @  @   @  @    @   ");
    puts(" @   @  @   @  @   @  @      @   @  @   @  @    @   ");
    puts("  @@@    @@@    @@@@   @@@    @@@@   @@@   @    @   ");
    puts("                                 @                  ");
    puts("                                 @                  ");
    puts("                              @@@                   ");
}
```

To compile: `gcc -o codegolf codegolf.c`, surprisingly `gcc`, at least my installation, doesn't complain about missing includes or returns.

Running:

```
 $ ./codegolf 
                   @                       @     @@ 
                   @                       @    @   
                   @                       @    @   
  @@@    @@@    @@@@   @@@    @@@@   @@@   @  @@@@@ 
 @   @  @   @  @   @  @   @  @   @  @   @  @    @   
 @      @   @  @   @  @@@@@  @   @  @   @  @    @   
 @   @  @   @  @   @  @      @   @  @   @  @    @   
  @@@    @@@    @@@@   @@@    @@@@   @@@   @    @   
                                 @                  
                                 @                  
                              @@@
```

If you squint your eyes and/or zoom out, it kind of looks okay!

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 9 bytes with updated rules

```
^v"\107"8
```

`v"\107"` evals a string containing `G`, octal escaped, which is the pyth variable for the alphabet.

`^G8`, is the result, which prints all 8 letter strings in the lowercase alphabet, including `codegolf`. Runs out of memory on my machine, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately, this uses the now-banned capital G. What bad luck with your choice of Pyth's letters!

Comment: @xnor Fixed. Only tripled the length.

Comment: This answer inspires me to suggest a new Pyth constant: A fixed, extremely long string of random characters. Or a De Brujin graph if you want to be efficient.

Comment: @xnor Would that help for any non trivial challenges?

Comment: Not really, I'm just amused at the idea of one-character solutions. Unless iterating over it saves chars when you want to do something a huge but finite number of times?

Comment: Actually, @xnor's idea could be somewhat useful in other cases. In xnor's wythoff question, I had to use `U39` to generate a list that was long enough to make each cold posisition. If I had needed 26 or less I could have used `UG`. I don't really know if it would be worth adding an arbitrarily long enumerable, but it would have other applications (Perhaps a -b flag for "big"?)

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (2,786 Bytes)

I'm not competing with this answer, just pointing out that it can be done.

```js
([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+[][(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+{}+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+{}+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]])())[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]])()([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+{}+[])[+!![]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]]((!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([]+{})[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+{}+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]])())[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]])()(([]+{})[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[]))+([]+{})[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]]
```

---

**Output:**

```
codegolf
```

Comment: I think most users of this site are already [aware of the existence of jsfuck](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=jsfuck)

Comment: Ooh. Sorry, I'm new.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
"r~utv~}w"{H^}%
```

I guess it should be shorter than Marbelous.

Answer (score 5):

### PHP, 13 bytes

```
<?=~œ›š˜“™;
```

StackExchange may swallow some of the control characters. Here's a hexdump of the program:

```
3c 3f 3d 7e 9c 90 9b 9a 98 90 93 99 3b
```

It bitwise inverts the string, and prints it using the PHP short tag syntax.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl - 12

```
say a.."z"x8
```

This also takes advantage of rule 3. It prints every word from `a` to `zzzzzzzz`.

Run with:

```
perl -E'say a.."z"x8'
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java, 118 Bytes

This is probably the lamest answer. Java programs have many key words. In order to print anything you have to use `System.out`. Despite all of these restrictions I can remove all of the letters in `codegolf` from my program except two letters.

With `c` and `o` allowed, 118 bytes:

```java
c\u006cass a{pub\u006cic static voi\u0064 main(String[]a){Syst\u0065m.out.print("\143\157\144\145\143\157\154\146");}}
```

With `l` and `o` allowed, 123 bytes:

```java
\u0063lass a{publi\u0063 stati\u0063 voi\u0064 main(String[]a){Syst\u0065m.out.print("\143\157\144\145\143\157\154\146");}}
```

With `c` and `f` allowed, 128 bytes:

```java
c\u006cass a{pub\u006cic static v\u006fi\u0064 main(String[]a){Syst\u0065m.\u006fut.print("\143\157\144\145\143\157\154\146");}}
```

With `l` and `f` allowed, 133 bytes:

```java
\u0063lass a{publi\u0063 stati\u0063 v\u006fi\u0064 main(String[]a){Syst\u0065m.\u006fut.print("\143\157\144\145\143\157\154\146");}}
```

With no restrictions on boilerplate code, 98 bytes:

```java
class a{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("\143\157\144\145\143\157\154\146");}}
```

Expanded:

```java
class a{
    
    public static void main(String[]a){
        System.out.print("\143\157\144\145\143\157\154\146");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think my answer is much lamer than yours!

Comment: Why not use a lambda? `()->"\143\157\144\145\143\157\154\146"` ?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Err... Java 8 was still pretty new, this answer is from late 2014.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 10 bytes

```
'P,{_m*}3*
```

It runs very slowly, and it should run out of memory on most computers. But if it exited successfully finally, it will print a lot of things including `CODEGOLF`.

Comment: `'P,` would save at least 66 exabytes of memory. :P

Answer (score 4):

## [Marbelous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40808/29588) - 9 bytes

```
7A
/\/\??
```

This will with a probability approaching 1 print a string containing all three acceptable outputs, since it prints an endless string of random ascii characters (up to and including the lowercase 'z' with ascii value 7A).
Nothing was specified about whether this program should terminate.
And just to make it clear, the characters get printed as they get generated, not after the program terminates (which is never).

Answer (score 3):

### Brainfuck (66 Bytes)

Can you do it in Brainfuck? Yes? Than I do it in Brainfuck!

```
++++[++++>---<]>.[->+++++<]>.-----------.+.++.++++++++.---.------.
```

**Output:**

```
CODEGOLF
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7, <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
print('%'+`map`[13])*8%(67,79,68,69,71,79,76,70)
```

**Output:**

```
CODEGOLF
```

This answer creates a format string using a 'c' found in the representation string of the built-in `map` function. The program then uses the format string to convert each integer into a character that creates the 'CODEGOLF' string.

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 20

```
4850170388041124934P
```

Prints the ASCII byte stream 0x434F4445474F4C46.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (29 bytes / 25 characters)

```
this['bt\x6fa']("àÄâÅ")
```

SE strips out the control characters, so here's a hex dump:

```
74 68 69 73 5B 27 62 74 5C 78 36 66 61 27 5D 28 22 08 C3 A0 C3 84 18 C3 A2 C3 85 22 29
```

### With escape characters (34 / 29)

```
this['bt\x6fa']("\bàÄ\x18âÅ")
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, 6 (12?) char

A sentence returning `CODEGOLF` at the REPL, along with every other combination of 8 ASCII characters and a whole bunch of spaces, newlines, and box-drawing characters.

```
{8#<a.
```

If you want to toss this into STDOUT, prepend `1!:2&4` to double the charcount.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <del>49</del> 48 bytes

-1 byte thanks to ceilingcat.

```
main(){int a[]={1701080931,1718382439};puts(a);}
```

## C11, <del>46</del> 45 bytes

```
main(){puts((int[]){1701080931,1718382439});}
```

It's obviously possible in C.

Works in 32bit little-endian systems.

Comment: Rule 3 lets you omit the `3` in the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck (145 Bytes)

```
+++++++++++[>++++++>++++++>++++++>++++++>++++++>++++++>++++++>++++++<<<<<<<<-]>+.>+++++++++++++.>++.>+++.>+++++.>+++++++++++++.>++++++++++.>++++.
```

---

**Output:**

```
CODEGOLF
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
"1n¯]"245bHb{'B+}%
```

This answer prints the result instantaneously without consuming infinite system memory :)

It is just base conversion of the string `CODEGOLF` to both save bytes and to avoid using any of the restricted characters.

[Just try it out here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, here we go again.

## **[The Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_Stacking_Pseudo-Assembly_Language)** (156):

(Technically not a valid entry, or so I'm told)

```
200066
400000
200063
400000
200009
400000
210000
200066
400000
200009
400000
210000
200067
400000
200065
400000
200064
400000
200066
400000
200009
400000
210000
200063
400000
140000
```

Output:

```
codegolf
```

Answer (score 1):

## Shell, 21

```
tr 2-@ A-P<<<4@568@=7
```

Answer (score 1):

## ROT13, 8 bytes

```
pbqrtbys
```

`rot13` is part of `bsdgames`.

Answer (score 1):

## Unnamed Two-Dimensional Programming Language, 26 bytes

```
67&79&68&69&71&79&76&70&s;
```

**Output:**

```
CODEGOLF
```

You can try it out [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/a/6252487852687360) (Replace the code in the `code()` function with this code).

If it is acceptable, the final semicolon can be removed and the program will loop infinitely (in theory, not in the interpreter, as the interpreter gives up after 2048 instructions to avoid a browser-crashing infinite loop)  for a score of **25 bytes**.

This works by pushing the values for the characters `CODEGOLF` to the stack, printing them, and terminating.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“£ṙɲI⁵»
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcwqPhuZnJsknigbXCuw&input=)

Comment: what is this witchcraft

Comment: @Syxer It's a valid Jelly program. This is a compressed string using Jelly's compression. You can see that because 1) `“` starts a string 2) `»` ends a compressed string. The string is then automatically output, no trailing newline AFAIK. To learn more about this language invented by Dennis, click on the Jelly link on my post.

Comment: Oh I know it's Jelly. Jelly witchcraft is scary though.

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy, 6 bytes

```
<ZR^72
```

This has a 1 in 36028797018963968 chance of printing the right order of characters per character output with ~10000 characters output a second. This means that, by 3.17 million years from now, you'll almost certainly have seen it.

:)

Using a method found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42376/44713).

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=PFpSXjcy&input=)

Answer (score 0):

**[Lua](http://www.lua.org/), 33 bytes**

CODEGOLF (33 bytes)

```
print("\67\79\68\69\71\79\76\70")
```

Codegolf (40 bytes)

```
print("\67\111\100\101\103\111\108\102")
```

codegolf (40 bytes)

```
print("\99\111\100\101\103\111\108\102")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
~aHpr
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7EaHpr)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
’ƒËŠˆ
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCZxpLDi8Wgy4Y&input=)