# Alphabet without the alphabet

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

You are tasked with displaying the string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and only that, except for trailing newlines if they're unavoidable.

You must not output any homoglyphic characters like Cyrillic A. You can use non-Unicode encodings, but just to be sure, only output the Latin letters.

Regardless of the encoding you pick, you must not use the characters from U+0041 to U+005A or from U+0061 to U+007A in your source.

No other cheats or loopholes are allowed.

This is a code golf challenge, so the shortest answer wins. However, I won't pick a winner answer since the shortest answer might change over time.

Comment: Can you specify forbidden unicode ranges? Your definition is not really clear; "lookalike" isn't a good criteria (is `Æ` allowed?)

Comment: I can *almost* do this in [Runic](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console/), the problem is that I need the `k` command to convert numbers to characters. Alternatives? `w` and `E`. :(

Comment: I have used `ASCII` compatible `PETSCII` for my answer as unicode wasn't a thing back in 1977 when the Commodore PET set this standard for all proceeding 8-bit Commodore computers.

Comment: Only I had already VTCed as unclear before the exact Unicode ranges were added, I would dupe hammer this in favour of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105781/58974

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 35 bytes

```
+++++++++++++[>++>+++++<<-]>[>.+<-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGxlE22lr24FZNja6sXbRdnraQPr/fwA)

This is the first language I thought of because it is really good for no-letter no-number challenges lol.

Answer (score 0):

## C64Mini/C64 BASIC (and other Commodore/CBM BASIC variants) 24 BASIC tokenized bytes used

In order to meet the criteria of "Regardless of the encoding you pick, you must not use the characters from U+0041 to U+005A or from U+0061 to U+007A in your source" (even though `Unicode` isn't a thing on the Commodore 64), you must enter this in "reverse mode" [`REVS ON`] by pressing `CTRL` or `Control` (or the equivalent on your emulator) and `9`.

In the screen shot, the screen codes for each character in my program is displayed after running it as I have read the memory from the start of screen RAM (top-left) (at 0x0400 or 1024) + 31 characters

```
 0FORI=65TO90:?CHR$(I);:NEXT
```

Simply starts from the 8-bit `PETSCII` `A` through to `Z` printing the character code with the `CHR$` command [source](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/CHR$)

[image: C64 Alphabet]

Comment: Doesn't this use letters...? Doesn't really matter because it's a duplicate challenge but still.

Comment: I thought the question was unclear actually if you read it. I read through carefully a few times and it's not clear to me anyway

Comment: Yeah, it is really unclear. Not using letters did seem to be a clear requirement though, unless I misinterpreted that as well. The other thing about lookalike characters made zero sense though.

Comment: "Regardless of the encoding you pick, you must not use the characters from U+0041 to U+005A or from U+0061 to U+007A in your source." - Unicode isn't a thing on the C64, it uses the `PETSCII` standard.

Comment: Oh hm. Well, ok then lol. Yeah this challenge ended up being more vaguely defined than it used to be somehow...

Comment: To make sure, I have used CBM `REVS ON` when I entered the listing, the characters used are shown in the screen grab.