# Tips for restricted source in Python

Tags: restricted-source, tips, python

Just like [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) pushes one to exploit quirks and hidden features of the Python language.  We already have [a place](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54) to collect all these [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), those for [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) remain transmitted by word of mouth or hidden deep within the python documentation.

So today I would like to ask you what are some [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) for solving [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenges in Python?

Please only include 1 tip per answer.

---

### What makes a good tip here?

There are a couple of criteria I think a good tip should have:

1. It should be (somewhat) non obvious.

   Similar to the [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) tips it should be something that someone who has golfed in python a bit and read the tips page would not immediately think of.  For example "Replace `a + b` with `a+b` to avoid using spaces", is obvious to any golfer, since it is already a way to make your code shorter.  Thus it is not a good tip here.
2. It should not be too specific.

   Since there are many different types of source restrictions, answers here should be at least somewhat applicable to multiple source restrictions, or one common source restriction.  For example tips of the form **How to X without using character(s) Y** are generally useful since banned characters is a common source restriction.  The thing your tip helps to do should also be somewhat general.  For example tips of the form **How to create numbers with X restriction** are useful since many programs utilize numbers regardless of the challenge.  Tips of the form **How to implement Shor's algorithm with X restriction** are basically just answers to a challenge you just invented and not very helpful to people solving other challenges.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207567/95207) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256014/does-python-forbid-two-similarly-looking-unicode-identifiers).

Comment: I think you can avoid `==` and `==0` with the `^` and `^0` operations. Does this count as a wat for doing restricted source?

Comment: Reading the answers, but pretending you are on codereview.SE is good entertainment.

Comment: Make use of answers from the [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110722/34718) challenge. [Another solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110676/34718)

Answer (score 32):

## Avoid "normal" letters

Identifiers are [normalized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62256014/2586922) by the Python 3 parser. This implies that cursive (Unicode) letters such as  are interpreted as their ASCII-compliant equivalents `abcDEF`. So the following code [works](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7//8PcyXNtDY2MuYCMnUC8G4g3AfF2IN6rAZLV/P8fAA) (as was exploited [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207563/36398)):

```
=123
()
```

Python versions in which this behaviour is confirmed:

- Works: 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8
- Doesn't work: 2.7

#### Example source restriction:

- *Use no characters `abc···xyz`, `ABC···XYZ`.*

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Anyway, this will *always* work in Python 3.7

Comment: I can confirm it works in 3.6.9, and doesn't in 2.7 (even with `#coding=utf8`)

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you! I have included this information in the answer

Comment: [This](https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi) text converter can help with this.

Answer (score 25):

## Avoid Numbers with Booleans

When performing arithmetic operations on Booleans, Python treats them as if they are the numbers 1 and 0.  So for example

```
>>> True+False
1
```

You can make all positive numbers by just adding booleans to each other.

You can also substitute the booleans for boolean values, for example `[]>[]` is `False` and `[[]]>[]` is `True` so

```
>>> ([]>[])+([[]]>[])
1
```

In some cases, Booleans can even be used in place of a number without having to using arithmetic to cast it.  For example, you can index into lists/tuples/strings with Booleans, so:

```
>>> ['a','b'][True]
'b'
```

---

#### Example source restrictions:

- *Use no digits (`0123456789`)*
- *Use no alphanumeric characters*
- *Use no `if` conditions*

Answer (score 22):

### Avoid Parens with List indexing

Parentheses are super useful for creating the correct operator precedence so it is a bummer when they are banned.  However if `[]` are still available we can use them instead.  Simply replace

```
(...)
```

with

```
[...][0]
```

This creates a list and indexes it to get its only element.  The list causes the inside to be evaluated first solving your precedence issue.

The example above uses the characters `[]0` to do this however there are other third characters that can be used in this case if need be.

- Using characters `[]>` write `[...][[]>[]]`
- Using characters `[]<` write `[...][[]<[]]`
- Using characters `[]=` write `[...][[[]]==[]]`

---

#### Example source restriction:

- *Use no parentheses*

Answer (score 20):

### Function calls without parentheses

[We can avoid using parentheses for operator precedence using list indexing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209737/56656), but parentheses are still very useful for calling functions.

List indexing can be used here as well to solve the issue, however it is a lot more complex so I've made it its own answer.

In order to call a function we start by making a new class which has it's indexing defined to be the function.  So if we want to call `print` this might look like

```
class c:__class_getitem__=print
```

Then to call the function we simply index it with the argument we want.  For example to print `"Hello World"` we do

```
c["Hello World"]
```

This has a few unfortunate short comings:

- It can only be used to call functions with one parameter.
- There are quite a few characters that are required to pull this trick off. ( `:=[]_acegilmst`)
- It uses up a lot of characters if you are doing [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

But sometimes it might be your only option.

---

### Example source restriction:

- Use no parentheses

[Here's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207662/56656) an example of it being used.

Comment: You can use multiple parameters with some `exec` abuse. [Here's an example](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzknsbhYIdUqPh7Mik9PLcksSc2Nj7dNrUhN5kqNViooyswriakwsijILwdRCkY6FgpAhiUIK8UqKCgoK4DUaoAVagBVaQBVaGpq/v8PAA)

Answer (score 18):

## Use `<<` and `|` to generate constant without `+`

Fun fact: You can get any positive constant only using `[]<|`. The way to go is left-shifting a boolean. `[]<[[]]` is 1, so `[]<[[]]<<[]<[[]]` should left-shift 1 with 1, which is 2.

Does it work?

```
>>> []<[[]]<<[]<[[]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    []<[[]]<<[]<[[]]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'list' and 'list'
```

...No.

The precedence is wrong. Luckily, we can resolve this with "Ad Hoc Garf Hunter Parenthesis(TM)":

```
>>> [[]<[[]]][[]<[]]<<[[]<[[]]][[]<[]]
2
```

Aha!

To get numbers other than power of two, you still need `+`... or not. `|` or `[bitwise or][[]<[]]`* will do that for you.

```
>>> [[]<[[]]][[]<[]]<<[[]<[[]]][[]<[]]<<[[]<[[]]][[]<[]]<<[[]<[[]]][[]<[]]|[[]<[[]]][[]<[]]<<[[]<[[]]][[]<[]]
10
```

To get negative numbers without `-`, you may want to use `~`.

* That part was enclosed in an "Ad Hoc Garf Hunter Parenthesis(TM)" to indicate precedence.

Comment: From these answers, it looks like Brainfuck is actually a subset of Python... That's interesting!

Answer (score 16):

### Access methods and built-in functions through `__dict__`

Classes contain a `__dict__` attribute, which maps their method names to the methods themselves. If you can't type a method name directly, you can get them from this `__dict__`.

For example, let's say you need to append something to a list, but you can't use the characters `p,n,+`, etc. Since `append()` is the 26th method in a list's `__dict__`, you can call the method like this:

```python
a = [1,2,3]
list(a.__class__.__dict__.values())[26](a, 4)
print(a)  # prints [1,2,3,4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBViHaUMdIxziWKyezuEQjUS8@Pjknsbg4Ph7ISslMLgEyyhJzSlOLNTQ1o43MYjUSdRRMNLkKijLzgMo1//8HAA)

This can also be used with `__builtins__` to access built-in functions. Even if someone bans the character `x` to block the `exec` function, you can still call `exec` like this:

```python
list(__builtins__.__dict__.values())[20]("print('Hello, World!')")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyezuEQjPj6pNDOnJDOvOD5eLz4@JTO5BMgoS8wpTS3W0NSMNjKI1VAqKMrMK9FQ90jNycnXUQjPL8pJUVTXVNL8/x8A)

This works best in more recent versions of Python that guarantee dictionary order, but there are probably other ways to use this in older versions, like iterating through the `__dict__` with a regex or substring match.

Comment: This is so convoluted and ridiculous.  I love it.

Comment: The index is 13 in Python 2.7.  Or `(ord(sys.version[0])*13-637)`

Answer (score 14):

### Use `ord()` or binary strings to avoid digits

Most integers in the ranges `[32..47]` and `[58..126]` can easily be obtained from the ASCII code of a single character with:

```python
x=ord('A')

# or, if parentheses are not allowed:

y=b'A'[False]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCoAgFAXQ3a@40GBBW1vg0NJPRIPRiwLxiQop4bdbbWc4LseT7VBrUuz3Vk6yE6IB@x7XAac92XhSoICPsByhjeGb9lGIrLbvL7M2gdbq/GVje8gEhSeVHvlHLrKrLw)

Larger integers can also be produced using from their unicode points:

```python
>>>print (ord("±"))
177
>>> print (ord("π"))
960
```

If you can use an assignment, or you need to avoid brackets you can unpack the values, instead. Note that this will not work inline, even with the walrus operator.

```python
x,*_=b'A'
y,_=b'A_'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0JHK942Sd1RnatSB8yIV/9fUJSZV6KRpl6hYKtQXVGro1AJYlTWqmv@BwA)

#### Example source restrictions:

- *Use no digits*
- *Use no digits / no parentheses / no brackets*

Answer (score 12):

### Alternatives to `eval` and `exec`

Do you need to treat a string as code, but you can't use `eval` or `exec`? There are at least three other ways to execute a string:

#### 1) timeit.timeit

```python
import timeit
_=timeit.timeit("print('Hello!')", number=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzc1s4Qr3hbC0INQGkoFRZl5JRrqHqk5OfmK6ppKOgp5pblJqUW2hpr//wMA)

`timeit` runs `number` times and returns an average of how long it took. By default it runs 1 million times, so you'll almost certainly want to set `number=1` or raise an exception to break out (e.g. `"print('hello'); 0/0"`).

Thanks to [Ethan White](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209878/94694) for showing me this approach.

#### 2) os.system

```python
import os
c='echo "import math;print(math.pi)" | python3'
_=os.system(c)  # Prints 3.141592653589793
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mCveNr9Yr7iyuCQ1V0M9NTkjX0EJKpmbWJJhrVBQlJlXogFi6xVkaiop1CgUQAxR1/z/HwA)

`os.system` runs an arbitrary shell command and returns its exit code. If you just need to print something, you can stick to `echo`, but you can also execute arbitrary code by calling `python3` itself.

#### 3) code.InteractiveInterpreter().runcode

```python
from code import InteractiveInterpreter as I
i = I()
i.runcode("print('Hello!')")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcs9CoAwDEDhvaeIXWwXF2d3ewypEQOalBgFT19/lse3vHLbKtzXuqjskGVGoL2IGiQ21CkbXfizKL6F6YDkCAZIITrq9ORvCr4osYV2xG2Tpo0@1voA)

`code` is specifically designed for read-eval-print loops, and even though it's a bit clunky, this is the most powerful of the three. `timeit` and `os.system` isolate their processes, but an `InteractiveInterpreter` can use global state instead of its own:

```python
from code import InteractiveInterpreter as I
a = 64
i = I(globals())
i.runcode("import math; a=math.log2(a)")
print(a)        # a = 6.0
print(math.pi)  # math is imported globally
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxCsMwDEV3n0JkspcMbelScgAfQ03dRGBbQlELPb3rhCz/Pfjw5Gcr12trb@UCM78SUBFWg1gtKc5G33SoaOoLuEF0CBPcb446ol8yPzFvPgRHo37qHvHDWSlo6wNw2jlmXi4ewxCcKFXresrxCoXW/g)

Comment: #4. Sympy ACE vulnerabilities

Comment: For the timeit.timeit approach if the code is the only thing you are executing you could avoid setting `number` by adding something to the end to stop execution before a second run.  For example `exit()` if you want to stop cleanly or a undeclared variable if you are fine with crashing the program.  [Proof of concept](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzc1s4Qr3hbC0INQGkoFRZl5JRrqHqk5OfmK6prWqRVAUU0lzf//AQ)

Answer (score 11):

### Use `--` to avoid +

E.g to do `a+b`:

```
a--b
```

**Example source restriction:**

- Avoid the `+` operator

Answer (score 5):

### Encode restricted characters and use `exec()`

Like most interpreted languages, Python can run a string as code with `eval` and `exec`. `eval` is more limited, but `exec` can handle imports, function definitions, loops, exceptions, etc.

When combined with some of the other tips about encoding characters, this allows you to write your code normally:

```
import sys

def f(i):
 return 1 if i==1 else i*f(i-1)

i=int(sys.argv[1])
print(f(i))
```

Then pick an encoding and pass the encoded version to `exec`:

```
exec('\x69\x6d\x70\x6f\x72\x74\x20\x73\x79\x73\x0a\x0a\x64\x65\x66\x20\x66\x28\x69\x29\x3a\x0a\x20\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x31\x20\x69\x66\x20\x69\x3d\x3d\x31\x20\x65\x6c\x73\x65\x20\x69\x2a\x66\x28\x69\x2d\x31\x29\x0a\x0a\x69\x3d\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x73\x79\x73\x2e\x61\x72\x67\x76\x5b\x31\x5d\x29\x0a\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x28\x66\x28\x69\x29\x29\x0a')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU87FsMgDDtO2i0x5XcXljSQl6nt0IGengpsXlMGPWEsyfbr8z6eD1VKymm7TCEbD8SQ7QzewQTcQibUVgGeeV4ZBj2jAcOaxo5zCFCia35ibc2zWurEPbWI35@yqj8Ker/O2niH@u46WofZ3eNPu0pem5HkLvd/F@HfLLKbBSNT3zlLx1@e7fcMWeP9rJ@upRT3BQ)

Answer (score 5):

### Replace operators with dunder methods

Most python operators are syntactic sugar for specific method calls (often called "magic methods" or "dunder methods", with "dunder" being short for "double underscore"). For example, `+` calls `__add__()`, `==` calls `__eq__()`, and `<<` calls `__lshift__()`

If operators are restricted, you can call these methods directly:

```python
a = 1
print(a.__add__(1).__eq__(2))  # True
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBVsGQq6AoM69EI1EvPj4xJSU@XsNQE8hMLQSyjDQ1//8HAA)

For assignment, you can use `__setitem__` on the `locals()` or `globals()` dictionaries, whether or not the variable already exists:

```python
a = 1
locals().__setitem__('a',2)
locals().__setitem__('b',2)
print(a.__add__(b).__eq__(4))  # True
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBVsGQKyc/OTGnWENTLz6@OLUksyQ1Nz5eQz1RXcdIE4dcEliuoCgzr0QjESiVmJICFE4CqUotBLJMNDX//wcA)

Note that you'll have to add parentheses around numbers to avoid a syntax error. `4.__eq__(4)` won't work, but `(4).__eq__(4)` will.

Comment: `4 .__eq__(4)` also works.

Comment: aha! Got it! Then my method of avoiding `+` is completely nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

## Use `__import__("module")` instead of `import module`

To avoid whitespace in the `import statement`, or to dynamically construct the name of the module to import as a string (e.g. `"RANDOM".lower()` if you can't use a lowercase `d`). Not likely that useful because you don't often need the standard library, and you still need to be able to use `_`, `i`, `m`, `p`, `o`, `r`, `t`, `(`, and `)`.

Edit: or as Ad Hoc Garf Hunter suggests, you can use `import<tab>module` (with a literal tab character)!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning, if you only need to avoid spaces you can just use a tab between `import` and the module name.

Comment: You can also assign the return value to an alias. For example, if you can't type `a`, you could use `m=__import__('MATH'.lower()); print(m.pi)`

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Pretty sure Python also accepts the "vertical tab" character.

Answer (score 5):

## File Encodings

You can set a custom encoding for your Python source file in a comment at the start. This includes various Unicode things, but also [text transforms](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) such as `unicode_escape` and `punycode`, which can be used for restricted source!

Here's an example:

```
# encoding: unicode_escape
print(\x22Hello, World!\x22)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3zZUVUvOS81My89KtFErzMoHM1PjU4uTEglSugqLMvBKNmAojI4_UnJx8HYXw_KKcFEWQgCZEO9QUmGkA)

Here's the exact specification of an encoding line, from [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations):

> If a comment in the first or second line of the Python script matches the regular expression `coding[=:]\s*([-\w.]+)`, this comment is processed as an encoding declaration; the first group of this expression names the encoding of the source code file

So, for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the best definition is therefore `#coding:unicode_escape`.

This works not only at the file level, but also with `exec` and `eval` *if you pass them a byte string*:

```
print(eval(rb'''# encoding: unicode_escape
\x22Hello, World!\x22'''))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3XQuKMvNKNFLLEnM0ipLU1dWVFVLzkvNTMvPSrRRK8zKBzNT41OLkxIJUrpgKIyOP1JycfB2F8PyinBRFkABQi6YmxDComTCzAQ)

Not as useful there though because you can generally just pass a constructed string.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `*` to avoid `/`

`x**-1` is equivalent to `1/x`. So to do `y/x` you can do `x**-1*y`.

If you desperately want to get rid of the `-1`, you can check out Ad Hoc Garf Hunter's other tip.

### Example source restriction:

- Avoid using the `/` character

Comment: You can also do `x**-y`

Answer (score 4):

This is likely not relevant to the question but it's very silly.

This is (maybe) a more portable way of water_ghost's convoluted method of accessing builtin methods.
The index is 26 only on CPython 3.   This very small and extremely easy to understand modification allows it to run on CPython 2.7, CPython 3, PyPy 2.7 and PyPy 3 (tested on Debian 10 amd64)

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
list(a.__class__.__dict__.values())[[14,13,26,25][sum(map(ord,{__import__("sys").version[0],__import__("platform").python_implementation()[0]}))&3]](a, 4)
print(a)
```

---

The correct indices (on my system) are

```
CPython 2.7    13
CPython 3      26
PyPy 2.7       26
PyPy 3         25
```

And by a lucky coincidence `('C'+'2')%4 == 1`, `('C'+'3')%4 == 2`, `('P'+'2') == 2` and `('P'+'3') == 3`.  The value 14 is there to trick you into thinking there is a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

### How to create characters just with numbers, quotes and backslashes

Strings can be composed with `\ooo` where `ooo` is the octal value of the character.

Eg:

```
'\141'=='a'
```

You can also use hex, at the expense of an `x` (and `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e` and/or `f` if they're used):

```
'\x61'=='a'
```

And unicode at the expense of a `u` (two pre-Python 3) and hex characters if they're used:

```
'\u2713'=='✓'
```

Answer (score 3):

## `__debug__` is True

Pretty self-expl... expl...

```
>>> __debug__
True
```

Comment: Ha! I figured out how to gain rep! Just post random comment-like answers everywhere!