Can Python be shown to be Turing-complete without the letters E or e anywhere in the code?
I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I wonder if Python can be shown to be Turing-complete without the use of the letter e in the source code.

Welcome to Code Golf! While [tag:restricted-source] questions are generally on-topic here (for example Fewest distinct characters for Turing Completeness), questions on this site are generally required to be competitive challenges and have an objective winning criterion - so for example "Write the shortest Python code to perform  without using e" would be on-topic.

If you do want to write that sort of challenge, consider using the sandbox so it can recieve feedback before being published to the main site.

You can write lambda and call functions without e, so it's TC because it can encode Lambda Calculus.

You can access exec as __builtins__.__dict__['\x65x\x65c'], then call it on whatever code with the escape \x65 for e.

This question is similar to: Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can simply replace e with ｅ

More information on what @tsh is saying can be found here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209742/56656
