# Output the alphabet with the shortest code possible

Tags: code-golf

You have to output the alphabet (upper case) with the shortest code possible.

Exact output expected : `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Answer (score 6):

## APL, 2 chars

```
⎕A
```

It's a constant string with the uppercase letters from A to Z

Answer (score 1):

### Python 35 chars

```
print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

Answer (score 1):

**BASH 21 chars**

```
echo {A..Z}|tr -d " "
```

Output:

```
~$ echo {A..Z}|tr -d " "
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: For a shorter way see the [`bash` solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2108) posted for this question's duplicate.

Comment: Sure, but the Output has to be exactly in the form provided. The answer you linked to is in lowercase with spaces. But nevertheless thank you for pointing me there :)

Comment: Interesting. `printf %s {A..Z}` gives me uppercase letters without any space.

Comment: Hmmm, true. Maybe you could then just submit this as an answer

Comment: Pointless. This question will be probably closed soon as duplicate. I only posted trying to help you get the taste of golfing.

Comment: Thanks for this and kudos for posting a better variant :)

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby 2.0.0, bytesize: 19:**

```
=> p([*'A'..'Z'].join)
=> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

**update. this produce without quotes:**

```
=> ruby -e '$><<[*?A..?Z].join'
=> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: You can use `?A` and `?Z` instead of `'A'` and `'Z'`. And you can use `*''` instead of `.join`. And the parenthesis is not necessary there. Sadly this outputs the alphabet between double quotes.

Comment: thanx @manatwork I'm surprised `*''`!

Answer (score 1):

### R, 19

```
cat(LETTERS,sep="")
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

### Delphi

#### 52 bytes

```
var i:int16;begin for i:=65to 90do write(chr(i))end.
```

#### 45 bytes

```
begin write('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');end.
```

Comment: You have to post a functional piece of code, including declarations and any other stuff required by the language.

Comment: Edited it, I thought you just needed the required code to display it... my bad

Comment: Actually the `program X;` is not necessary and in this case `byte` is enough. Not mentioning that the variable declaration in the second version is pointless.

Comment: **sighs** could get it shorter anyhow, just had something coming up all of a sudden, I will edit it soon..