# Crack the code to the combination lock

Tags: code-golf

Given a standard combination lock like the one in the picture. The way to unlock it is to align the 4 numbers in the code on the combination line. After years of loyal service you have been fired from the lock factory and have decided to exact revenge by not jumbling up the locks before you send them off, thus leaving every lock with the combination to unlock it on the combination line.

[image: Combination lock]

You also know that by looking at the order of the numbers in the other lines it is possible to work out what numbers must be on the combination line (and therefore the combination to unlock it is).

If every line on the lock is given a number starting from line 0 for the combination line (the line which unlocks the lock) to line 9. For example, if the numbers on line 4 are `5336`, then the combination to unlock it would be `1992`.

Unfortunately the locks have already been packaged and your view of each lock is obscured, so you can only see numbers on different lines of the lock.

**The Challenge**

Given 4 pairs of digits, where the first digit of the integer represents the line number and the second digit represents the the number which appears on that line, work out the combination to the lock.
For example if you input:

```
57 23 99 45
```

Then it should output:

```
2101
```

Or

```
25 78 63 15
```

and

```
3174
```

Assume the input will always be 4 positive integers in the form `25 64 72 18.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest programs in number of bytes wins.

Also this is my first question, so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the input. You say "*Given 4 pairs of integers*" and then give an example `57 23 99 45`. That's not four pairs of integers: it's four integers. And some answers are assuming they get that as a string, whereas others are assuming that it comes ready-parsed as 4 ints.

Comment: I disagree, the fact that it said four pairs of integers made the format of the input clear, 57 is the integer pair 5 and 7, not the integer 57.  My first assumption was that the line was 57 and the combination was 23.

Comment: How about "pairs of digits?" That would be much more clear and precise (and also works with leading `0`s).

Comment: Technically, the correct term would be *permutation lock*. Most "combination locks" are actually permutation locks, because the order of the digits makes a difference.

Comment: _Technically_ yes it is correct, but I don't think makes for a catchy title.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## CJam, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ea9fbAf%
```

Reads the digit pairs as command-line arguments. To [try the code online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/), change `ea` to `lS/` to read from simulated STDIN.

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo ea9fbAf%) 57 23 99 45; echo
2101
$ cjam <(echo ea9fbAf%) 25 78 63 15; echo
3174
```

#### How it works

The character code of the digit **d** is **48 + d**. Thus, considering the two-digit string **xy** a base 9 number yields **9 * (48 + x) + (48 + y) = 10 * (48 + x) + y - x ≡ y - x (mod 10)**.

```
ea       " Push the array of command-line arguments.                                      ";
  9fb    " Mapped base 9 conversion; replace each string 'xy' with (9 * ord(x) + ord(y)). ";
     Af% " Take the results modulo 10.                                                    ";
```

Comment: Dammit, you can't let anyone else win, no ? :P

Comment: I don't think we'll get a better CJam answer than this

Comment: What just happened there?

Comment: As many bytes of code as there are bytes of (meaningful) input. Crazy.

Comment: Very clever!  Though I'm not quite sure how `99` can be read as a base 9 number - I guess each digit is taken mod 9 before interpretation?  Interestingly `dc` seems to do something similar, so I'm borrowing this trick for my (longer) answer, if thats OK?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Sure, go ahead. The string `"99"` is actually interpreted as the array `[57 57]` by `b`; `"xy"9b` is implemented as `9 * ord(x) + ord(y)`. I should add that to my answer.

Comment: CJam is compact enough that you can probably generate the answers to most of these questions with brute force.  Just try all the possible programs of increasing length up to maybe 10,000 steps.

Comment: 10,000 barely covers all 2-character programs *if* we restrict possible solutions to printable ASCII.

Answer (score 13):

## CJam, <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 characters

Thanks to user23013, its now down to 11 characters :)

```
4{Ar:--A%}*
```

Explanations:

```
4{       }*     "Run the code block 4 times";
   r            "Read the next input token (whitespace separated)";
    :-          "Subtract 2nd number from the first treating r as a 2 numbered string";
  A   -         "Subtract the result of above from 10";
       A%       "Take modulus of 10 and store it on stack";
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

I know it can be golfed more. But this is my first real attempt on CJam and I am limited by experience :)

---

Alternatively, the other methods to do the same thing in 1 extra character:

```
l~]{_A/-A%}/     // My previous solution
```

or

```
4{ri_A/-A%}*     // As pointed out by Ingo
```

or

```
ea{i_A/-A%}/     // If input is passed through command line
```

Comment: I was waiting for this. Well, next week...

Comment: The first three characters could alternatively be `l~]`. I feel like parsing the input should be possible with less than three, but I've never used CJam before :/

Comment: `4{ri_A/-A%}*` is one byte shorter.

Comment: Ah, or what you made from my earlier comment. Well now there are two 12 byte solutions! :)

Comment: Or `4{Ar:--A%}*`.

Comment: Now if only CJam also allowed non-matched `}`s similar to `]`. I love the purity of CJam here – the code does exactly the steps logically involved without hiding them in built-in commands. It's very satisfying.

Answer (score 6):

## Golfscript (14 <s>13</s>)

[Try it online here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIyNSA3OCA2MyAxNSIKfl17LjEwOl4vLV4lfS8%3D)

It's pretty much the same as [Optimizer's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37790/26765), but in a different language. It's hard to approach it in a different way because the problem is fairly simple<s>, so the tie definitely goes to Optimizer, whose entry was earlier anyway.</s>

```
~]{.10:^/-^%}/
```

For the same number of bytes you can do

```
~]{.10/- 10%}/
```

Comment: No pre defined variable with value 10 in Golfscript ?

Comment: @Optimizer Unfortunately, no. Too bad, because having the input on the stack already would be the advantage over CJam.

Comment: Yeah, it can be 10 characters in CJam (with input on stack) or 11 in Golfscript (with pre defined variable)

Comment: I could have 12 in Golfscript as well if only I didn't have to leave the space in `- 10`.

Comment: heh, even the shortest of languages have their **short** comings :P

Comment: But the standard input on the stack should be a *string*.

Comment: @Optimizer In fact there is a predefined string of character 10... But there is no easy way to use it.

Comment: @user23013 You're right. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 6):

**C <strike>64</strike> <strike>63</strike> 56 or 61**

If the input can be piped from file

```
main(a){while(scanf("%d",&a)>0)putchar(48+(a-a/10)%10);}
```

If the input should be typed to stdin

```
i;main(a){for(;i++-4;putchar(48+(a-a/10)%10))scanf("%d",&a);}
```

Reads the four numbers in a loop and then processes each by subtracting the first digit from the value and printing the result modulo 10.

Savings thanks to various comments below and also using putchar instead of printf

Comment: Cool. You can save a comma by putting the `scanf` outside the `for()` like this `a,i;main(){for(;i++-4;printf("%d",(a-a/10)%10))scanf("%d",&a);}`

Comment: You could also save 2 bytes by using `a*.9` instead of `a-a/10`

Comment: @steveverrill Like it.  So focussed on putting everything in the for loop that I missed that

Comment: @AcidShout Sorry - it doesn't work. For example 78 * .9 = 70.2, while 78 - 78/10 = 71.   Also using .9 promotes the argument to a double so I can't take the mod.

Comment: You could save a few bytes by using a `while` loop and declaring `a` as an argument of `main`: `main(a){while(scanf("%d",&a)>0)printf("%d",(a-a/10)%10);}`

Comment: @Dennis On my system at least, scanf continues waiting for input so the program does not terminate, although I agree that it gives the right output first.  Feels like cheating though, which is why I had to add the loop counter.

Comment: Did you type in the numbers or pipe them? With piped input, `scanf` should return `-1` (EOF), causing the program to terminate.

Comment: Typed, according to input spec as I read it.  Good point though.  If the OP allows it that would save several characters.  I'll certainly remember that for future challenges too.

Answer (score 6):

## [GNU dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 14 bytes

Borrowing [@Dennis's clever base 9 trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37815/11259):

```
9i[?A%nd]dxxxx
```

Input integers read from STDIN, one per line.

#### Explanation:

```
9i                # Set input radix to 9
  [     ]         # push a macro, defined thus:
   ?              #   read number from STDIN and push
    A             #   push literal 10
     %            #   calculate number mod 10
      n           #   print, with no newline
       d          #   duplicate macro
         d        # duplicate macro
          xxxx    # execute the macro 4 times
```

#### Output:

```
$ for i in 57 23 99 45; do echo $i; done | dc ./combolock.dc
2101$ 
$ for i in 25 78 63 15; do echo $i; done | dc ./combolock.dc
3174$ 
$
```

---

#### Previous Answer, 18 bytes:

Because I thought I could get closer to the "golfing" languages with this (but didn't):

```
[A?A~--A%n]dddxxxx
```

Comment: You can save a byte: `9i[?A%nd]dxxxx`

Comment: @Dennis - Fantastic! Now I'm neck-and-neck with golfscript and APL!

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3 , 64

Straightforward.

```
print(''.join([(i-i//10)%10 for i in map(int,input().split())]))
```

It can be shorter if I'm allowed to print, say, `[2, 1, 0, 1]` instead (**46**):

```
print([i%10-i//10 for i in map(int,input().split())])
```

Comment: You can save some by taking `str((i-i//10)%10)` directly instead of using a second `map()`.  I started with generators too for mine, but found that an actual `for` loop ended up being shorter.

Comment: Yup, thanks for that!

Comment: Why are you using list-comprehensions? Use genexps to save 2 characters: `print(''.join((i-i//10)%10for i in map(int,input().split())))`. Also if spaces are allowd in the output you can avoid `join` and use tuple-unpacking: `print(*((i-i//10)%10for i in map(int,input().split())))`.

Comment: I guess you're right.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 92

```
#define a(n) ,(10+v[n][1]-*v[n])%10
main(int c,char**v){printf("%d%d%d%d"a(1)a(2)a(3)a(4));}
```

Input from commandline. Subtracts the first ASCII code of each argument from the second, adds 10 and takes modulo 10.

I think this is the first time I've written a `printf` with four `%`s and no comma (the comma is in the  `#define.`)

Comment: `#define f scanf("%c%c ",&a,&b);putchar(48+(9*a+b)%10)` followed by `a,b;main(){f;f;f;f;}` would be 18 bytes shorter.

Comment: @Dennis that's a great improvement, but it's basically a completely different program. I think if anyone posts it, it should be you, not me. I'm not sure if the space in `scanf` is necessary, given that `scanf` is supposed to parse whitespace only as a separator. Alchymist has an even better idea in C. But it looks like you've already won it with your Cjam answer.

Comment: Yeah, I started by noticing that the space after `a(n)` can be omitted, then I noticed that putting `printf("%d%,...)` around your macro would save a few bytes and finally I got a little carried away... -- The space is needed since `%c` reads a character, *any* character, so on the second run it would store 32 in `a`. -- Beating CJam with C should prove to be hard. `printf()` is already as long as  my answer...

Answer (score 4):

### Java - 203 bytes

Just because there *has* to be a Java entry, I saw a nice opportunity to give this code golfing a chance (first submission ever).

```
class M{public static void main(String[] a){String r="";for(int i=0;i<4;i++){int l=Byte.valueOf(a[i].substring(1));int f=Byte.valueOf(a[i].substring(0,1));r+=(l-f<0)?l-f+10:l-f;}System.out.print(r);}}
```

If there's room for some improvements, I'd glad to know about them ;-)

Comment: You can search [tips] and get various tips about golfing to get you started :)

Comment: Cool, thanks! Checking out some tips helped me shaving off 13 bytes :)

Answer (score 3):

## Lua - 46 characters

```
while''do a,b=io.read(1,1,1)print((b-a)%10)end
```

Reads three characters at a time (grant me the small mercy of inputing a space at the end), and eventhough a and b are string-y... b-a MAGICALUALY allows them to conceive a healthy baby integer. Does the wrap-around check while printing.

[image: How I run it:]

Comment: Could you provide an example data input/output, can't seem to get it to run on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: @Harry12345 Ah, sorry about that. Anarchy Golf is setting my mind on how I implement stdinput. I could probably code it better, but meh, lua is terrible. I posted an example of me running the program.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6 – <s>53</s> 43 bytes

```js
f=n=>n.replace(/.. ?/g,a=>(1+a[1]-a[0])%10)
```

Fairly straightforward function, uses regex to get the numbers. Try it out at http://jsfiddle.net/efc93986/1/. If functions are not allowed, a standalone program at 52 bytes:

```js
alert(prompt().replace(/.. ?/g,a=>(1+a[1]-a[0])%10))
```

As ES6 currently only works on Firefox, the following code works on any modern browser, at 70 bytes:

```js
alert(prompt().replace(/.. ?/g,function(a){return(1+a[1]-a[0])%10}))
```

Comment: I love your `1+`.

Comment: The question says to assume valid input, so you can use `...?` instead of `/\d+ ?`. The space after return can be omitted. Also, since no specific I/O was specified, you should be able to use a function.

Comment: `a-a[0]` instead of `1+a[1]-a[0]` should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - 33 bytes

```
for i in input():print(i-i/10)%10
```

Accepts comma-delimited user input.
E.g. Input:

```
29,26, 31, 88
```

Output:

```
7
4
8
0
```

If output is required to exactly match the example then it is much longer. 47 bytes:

```
print"%d"*4%tuple((i-i/10)%10 for i in input())
```

Comment: `input()` doesn't work in my Python 2 interpreter.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury did you use commas?

Comment: Oh, no, I didn't. It works now.
On a side note, I *think* you need to take space-delimited input per the spec.

Comment: I agree, input should be space de-limited

Answer (score 2):

### APL, 14

```
10|{--/⍎¨⍕⍵}¨⎕
```

**Explaination**
`⎕` takes input from screen. Space-separated values are parsed as an array.
`{...}¨` for each number, feed it into function.
`⍎¨⍕⍵` takes the argument, create an array of its digits.
`--/` calculates units minus tens.
`10|` mod 10.

Comment: This may be 14 characters, but it is 24 *bytes*.

Comment: @IngoBürk http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/the-alphabet-in-programming-languages/2127#2127

Comment: but for code golf we count in UTF-8, not some special charset. That'd just be a loophole and could be abused very easily.

Comment: @IngoBürk As per http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/961/6972 answers can be encoded in any encoding unless the OP states otherwise. There is indeed an IBM codepage for APL characters which is a single-byte mapping, which is exactly what Dyalog used to use before Unicode 3.0. If you insist on Unicode, what if I invent a new language that uses non-Unicode characters? How would you count bytes for that?

Comment: I could've sworn the default was UTF-8. 14 bytes it is, then.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell <strike>60</strike> 58

```
main=interact$show.map((\x->mod(x-x`div`10)10).read).words
```

Single character digits, a real nemesis in Haskell golfing.

Answer (score 2):

### J - <strike>20</strike> 15

The non-verb form (as statement instead of function definition) it's 5 characters shorter:

```
10|-~/|:10#.inv
```

The verb form which is a nice [train](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm):

```
10|[:-~/[:|:10#.inv]
```

This verb used on the example inputs:

```
   10|-~/|:10#.inv 57 23 99 45
2 1 0 1
   10|-~/|:10#.inv 25 78 63 15
3 1 7 4

rotd =: 10|[:-~/[:|:10#.inv] NB. verb form

   rotd 25 78 63 15
3 1 7 4
   rotd 57 23 99 45
2 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl: <strike>38</strike> 40

```
print abs($_-int$_/10)%10for split" ",<>
```

Output:

```
% perl code.pl
57 23 99 45
2101

25 78 63 15                                     
3174
```

Comment: 1. Underscores are markdown syntax, so your code got a little messed up. To prevent this, indent code with four spaces. 2. `abs` isn't necessary; `x - x/10` cannot be negative. 3. If you use the flags `-040pe` (usually counted as 5 bytes) to iterate over space-delimited input, you  can shorten your code to `$_=($_-int$_/10)%10`. 4. If you prefer to avoid command-line flags, you can still save a few bytes by setting `$/=$;` and removing the call to `split`.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 35 bytes

```
$*.map{|n|a,b=n.bytes;$><<(b-a)%10}
```

#### Explanation

Input is taken as command line arguments. `String#bytes` returns an Array of Integers (ASCII character codes). Only the difference between the last and first character code is of importance, not the Integers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 118

```
int main()
{
int a,b,c;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
cin>>a;
b=a/10;
a=a%10;
c=a-b;
if(c<0)c+=10;
cout<<c;
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Not sure about other compilers, but GCC requires `#include<iostream>` and `std::` before `cin` and `cout`. 2. You don't need the conditional if you omit `a=a%10`. 3. You don't need the variables `b` and `c`, the linefeeds and (with a few modification) the brackets around the for loop.

Comment: @SeanD: Please don't approve edits that modify code. In this particular case, the edit made the answer invalid. It also removed the first line, which should be present in all answers.

Comment: (CC @TeunPronk)

Comment: @Dennis usually answers on this site don't include preprocessor lines. I omitted the lines `#include<iostream>`and `using namespace std;`

Comment: I know there not usually included in the byte count, but I think they should be present in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**C# & LinqPad: 104**

```
Util.ReadLine<string>("").Split(' ').Select(s =>(s[1]-s[0])).Aggregate("",(r,a)=>r+(a<0?10+a:a)).Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 90 characters

Thought I'd give code golf a try so here it is, my first attempt - can probably be golfed more.

```
<?php $a=array(57,23,99,45);foreach($a as$b){echo abs(substr($b,0,1)-substr($b,1,1)%10);}
```

### 58 characters (courtesy of Ismael Miguel)

```
for($i=0,$a=$_GET[n];$i<8;)echo abs($a[$i++]-$a[$i++]);
```

Access file using

```
file.php?n=57239945
```

Comment: Try this code: `<? for($i=0;$i<4;)echo abs($_GET[n][$i]%10);` which is 44 chars long. Access from a browser using `file.php?n[]=xx&n[]=yy&n[]=xy&n[]=yx`. (untested code)

Comment: Good idea using `$_GET` but it displays 57%10 and I need (5-7)%10

Comment: Try this one: `<? for($i=0,$a=$_GET[n];$i<4;++$i)echo abs($a[$i][0]-$a[$i++][1]%10);`. Sadly, it's 65 bytes long. (forgot the `$i` increment on the last one) Or you could try `<? for($i=0;$i<8;)echo abs($_GET[n][$i++]-$_GET[n][$i++]%10);` and access the browser using `file.php?n[]=x&n[]=y&n[]=x&n[]=y&n[]=x&n[]=y&n[]=x&n[]=y`, being 61 bytes long.

Comment: Yeah the second ones works, need to do `$_GET['n']` tho. Have edited my answer.

Comment: Well, it isn't required. It simply issues a warning. That is fine for this website. But try this one: `<? for($i=0,$a=$_GET[n];$i<8;)echo abs($a[$i++]-$a[$i++]);`. The `%10` is useless and this one simply looks better. Also, you can access it using `file.php?n[]=xyxyxyxy`. This solution is 58 bytes long.

Comment: Good work! Think I'm going to need to practice some more

Comment: No one is perfect, I'm not perfect. As you could see, I made some mistakes on the way. If you are worried about warnings, you can replace `$a=$_GET[n]` with `@$a=$_GET[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 60

```
for x in input().split():print(-eval('-'.join(x))%10,end='')
```

Input and output exactly as specified, although it doesn't print a trailing newline.  Two interesting tricks here: 1) replacing two calls to `int()` with one call to `eval()`, and 2) using `join()` to get `a-b`, then negating it for `b-a` as required.  Fortunately Python's modulo operator gives positive values even if the first argument is negative!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It works perfectly fine. (Btw, the `eval('-'.join(x))` trick is brilliant.)

Comment: @flornquake Thanks!