# Output the alphabet, the ALPHABET, or just a character

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

The challenge is simple:

Write a function or program that takes an input `x`, and outputs the lower case alphabet if `x` is part of the lower case alphabet, outputs the upper case alphabet if `x` is part of the upper case alphabet and outputs just `x` if it's not part of either.

Rules:

- The input can be function argument or from STDIN
- The input will be any of the printable ASCII characters from 32 to 126 (space to tilde).
- The input may be inside quotation marks,`'x'` or `"x"`, but remember that `'` and `"` are valid input and should be supported.
- The input can be any of the letters in the alphabet, i.e. you can't assume it will be `a` or `A`.
- The output should be only one of the alphabets or the single symbol, but trailing newlines are OK.
- The letters in the alphabet should not be separated by spaces, commas or anything else.

Some examples:

```
F
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

z
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

"
"

    <- Input:  Space
    <- Output: Space
```

Shortest code in bytes win.

---

Optional but appreciated: If your language has an online interpreter, please also post a link so that it can be easily tested by others.

---

### Leaderboard

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=67357,OVERRIDE_USER=44713;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Are we allowed to import packages like, in Python for example: `import Random` and then use `Random.randint` (obviously not for this challenge but still)?

Comment: Yes, you may import packages. but the bytes for writing for instance `import string` are counted, thus it's often better to do workarounds. Note that the package must exist before the challenge is posted. Many challenges have something like: "Using packages that does this is not allowed", but that is not the case in this challenge.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "quotes are valid input and must be supported" you mean that if your input method requires quotes then quotes as input would be escaped

Comment: May we assume a REPL environment?

Comment: Is it single char input?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 5 bytes

```
xN(0)
```

TeaScript has a (almost) built-in for this :D

[Try it online](https://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22xN(0)%22&inputs=%5B%22a%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D) (note: the online interpreter has been updated to TeaScript v3 so in which this is `N0`)

[Try all the test cases](https://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22_m(%23(x%3Dl,%20%20xN(0)%20%20))j%60%5Cn%60%22&inputs=%5B%22A%22,%22b%22,%221%22,%22%20%22,%22%5C%22%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:false,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

---

#### [TeaScript 3](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript/tree/master/beta), 2 bytes [non-competing]

Using TeaScript 3, this can become 2-bytes. This is non-competing because TeaScript 3 was made after this challenge

```
N0
```

---

#### 1 byte alternative

If we could output `0123456789` for digits, then this could be:

```
°
```

Comment: TeaScript 3 ***is*** valid. So, you may use it!

Answer (score 27):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
h/#z[GrG1z
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h%2F%23z%5BGrG1z&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=F%0Az%0A%22%0A+&debug=0)

We start by constructing a list with 3 elements: the lowercase alphabet, the uppercase alphabet, and the input. (`[GrG1z`) Then, we filter this list on the number of appearances of the input in the elements being nonzero. (`/#z`) Finally, we take the first element of the filtered list.

Comment: Seriously, is there anything you couldn't solve with a few bytes of Pyth? I really need to learn this language..

Comment: Learn which language?...you mentioned two by name. :P

Comment: @quintopia Well, why not both? :)

Comment: Holy cow, this is clever! I just went with the obvious solution of ternary statements, which ended up being 14 bytes

`?}zGG?}zKrG1Kz`

Answer (score 15):

## LabVIEW, 23 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

The selector (the ? on the cse structure) is connected to a vi that is called Lexical Class. It ouputs numbers from 1-6 depending on input, 5 is lower case 4 is upper case.

The for loop goes 26 times to create an alphabet or once to pass the symbol through.

[image]

Comment: As someone who had the (privilege? misfortune? you decide) of working in LabVIEW many years ago, your answers bring a smile to my day. =)

Answer (score 12):

### Haskell, 48 bytes

```
f c=filter(elem c)[['a'..'z'],['A'..'Z'],[c]]!!0
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> f 'g'
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
*Main> f 'H'
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
*Main> f '\''
"'"
```

Take all lists of ['a'..'z'], ['A'..'Z'] and the singleton list with the input char `c` where `c` is element of. For letters we have always two matches, so we pick the first one.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

```js
x=>(a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",x>"`"&x<"{"?a:x>"@"&x<"["?a.toUpperCase():x)
```

### Explanation

JavaScript compares the code of each character alphabetically when comparing strings, so the codes of the characters used in the comparisons are 1 below and above the required range of characters.

```js
x=>(
  a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", // a = lower-case alphabet
  x>"`"&x<"{"?a:                  // if x is a lower-case letter, output alphabet
  x>"@"&x<"["?a.toUpperCase():    // if x is an upper-case letter, output upper-case
  x                               // else just output x
)
```

### Test

```js
var solution = x=>(a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",x>"`"&x<"{"?a:x>"@"&x<"["?a.toUpperCase():x)
```

```html
X = <input type="text" oninput="result.textContent=solution(this.value)" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Is that actually the shortest way to produce a string with the entire alphabet in Javascript? If you wanted the entire printable ASCII-range, would you have to type every single character?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Sadly it is. The only other way would be something like: `for(a="",i=64;++i<91;)a+=String.fromCharCode(i)`. `String.fromCharCode` is very unsuitable for golfing, but sometimes it's the only way!

Comment: In this case the balance is between `String.fromCharCode` and `.toUpperCase` (Dumb and Dumber) but `toUpperCase` is the winner

Comment: Nice! I've tried a few different ways of golfing this further, but haven't found one that works. ``x=>x.replace(/[A-Z]/i,c=>c>"`"?a:a.toUpperCase(),a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")`` does, but is one byte longer. Changing `[A-Z]` to `\w` works for everything except `_`. Your solution seems to be the shortest possible.

Comment: Here's one of the shortests way to generate `ABC...abc...?` without a real `for` loop: (some padding) `[for(_ of[...Array(i=64)])if(i++%32<26)String.fromCharCode(i)].join``+x`

Comment: @ETHproductions I was wondering about that; the best I had managed was `String.fromCharCode(...Array(91).keys()).slice(65)` which takes 50 bytes just to produce the uppercase alphabet, or `String.fromCharCode(...Array(123).keys()).replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'')` which concatenates both in "only" 64 bytes.

Comment: Bah, `/[^\W_]/` is no shorter than `/[A-Z]/i`.

Answer (score 9):

### R, <s>90</s> 75 bytes

```
a=scan(,'');l=letters;L=LETTERS;cat("if"(a%in%l,l,"if"(a%in%L,L,a)),sep="")
```

Thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).

Old version (90 bytes):

```
a=scan(,'');l=letters;L=LETTERS;if(a%in%l)cat(l,sep="")else if(a%in%L)cat(L,sep="")else a
```

Looks ugly, but those `cat`s cannot be outsourced to functions, IMHO.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2ODkxT0NHXV3TOsc2J7WkJLWo2NrH1sc1JMQ1KNg6ObFEQykzTUkjUTUzTzVHJ0cHwfPR8dFJ1NTUKU4tsFVS0vxf9x8A "R – Try It Online")

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2ODkxT0Mnx0Y3J7WkJLWoWNPax9bHNSTENSjYOjmxREMpM01JI1E1M081RydHB8Hz0fHRSdTU1ClOLbBVUtL8H/QfAA "R – Try It Online"): the 2nd parameter of `scan` can be any object of type character, so you can `letters` instead of `''`.

Comment: Can you replace the last `sep=""` with just the `""`?

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, <s>92</s> <s>84</s> <s>82</s> 74 bytes

Current version: 74, thanks to isaacg and wnnmaw!

```
lambda c:(c,''.join(chr(x+(67,97)[c>'Z'])for x in range(25)))[c.isalpha()]
```

Ungolfed: (for some definition of ungolfed)

```
lambda c:
    (
        c,
        ''.join([chr(x + (67,97)[c > 'Z']) for x in range(25)])
    )
    [c.isalpha()]
```

---

First version: 92

```
def f(c):print(''.join([chr(x+(97if c>'Z'else 65)) for x in range(25)])if c.isalpha()else c)
```

Second version: 82, thanks to isaacg! :)

```
lambda c:''.join(chr(x+(97if c>'Z'else 65))for x in range(25))if c.isalpha()else c
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! Nice answer. Here's a golfing suggestion: You can use a lambda expression (`lambda c:`) instead of an explicit definition (`def f(c):print(`), and save some bytes. Also, you don't need the space before the `for`.

Comment: Ah, I assumed "output" to mean print, and not just return :) Neat, if that's the case it's down to 84, `lambda c:''.join([chr(x+(97if c>'Z'else 65))for x in range(25)])if c.isalpha()else c`. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the standard definition of output on the site allow returning from functions, so you can edit the new version into your answer. Another golf is that the brackets aren't necessary - the function works exactly the same without them, as a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: Ah, haven't actually used generator comprehensions before, learning new things! Thanks again :)

Comment: Note that when inputing `"` to the function, you need `\"` instead.

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by replacing `(97if c>'Z'else 65)` with `(67,97)[c>'Z']`

Comment: True! We can actually use the same trick to replace the if else. Down to 76, neat! :)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, <s>118</s> <s>105</s> <s>98</s> <s>97</s> 83 bytes

Simple solution. **EDIT:** Golfed with thanks to Erik the Golfer's suggestion.

```
lambda s,a='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':(s,(a,a.lower())[s.islower()])[s.isalpha()]
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(s):
 a='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 if s.isalpha():
  if s.islower():return a.lower()
  else:return a
 return s
```

Comment: Could you use a ternary operator to save a few bytes? Something like `return a.lower() if s.islower() else a`.

Comment: @DavidRobertson I'm not sure if you're reading my solution, which is the top line of code, correctly, but that is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah! I was reading the ungolfed version. Sorry about that!

Comment: @DavidRobertson Not a problem

Comment: Golfed: `lambda s,a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':(s,(a,a.upper())[s.isupper()])[s.isalpha()]`

Comment: Can you do something like `map(chr,range(65,91))`?

Comment: @Cyoce I don't think I can. I can't `.lower()` a `map` and `''.join` would add too many bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 62 <s>76</s> <s>82</s> bytes

PHP is doing OK now:

```
<?=ctype_alpha($x=$argv[1])?join(range(Z<$x?a:A,Z<$x?z:Z)):$x;
```

Takes an input from command line, like:

```
$ php alphabet.php A
$ php alphabet.php "a"
$ php alphabet.php " "
$ php alphabet.php _
```

**Edits**

- *Saved* **6 bytes** by replacing `91>ord($x)` with `Z<$x`. Thought way to complicated. Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork).
- *Saved* **14 bytes** by removing `strtoupper` and building the demanded range directly.

Comment: That `ord()` looks bad there. Try `Z<$x?$a:strtoupper($a)`.

Comment: @manatwork Haha, I've thought way to complicated in that second part. Thanks to point it out.

Comment: Try `' '&$x^A` to make uppercase and lowercase a and z. That is, your code becomes `<?=ctype_alpha($x=$argv[1])?join(range(' '&$x^A,' '&$x^Z)):$x;`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel This will have the exact same byte count.

Comment: @insertusernamehere -.- you're right... I counted those bytes incorrectly. sorry :/

Comment: Don't worry - and it's still a nice way to obfuscate. ;)

Comment: Wow, I just php-golfed this challenge myself as an exercise and came up with exactly this code, byte for byte.

Comment: Save 4 bytes with `range($x&a|A,$x&z|Z)` and one byte with `$argn` and `-R`.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>46</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

*includes +2 for `-nE`*

```pl
say/[a-z]/?a..z:/[A-Z]/?A..Z:$_
```

Run as

```
perl -nE 'say/[a-z]/?a..z:/[A-Z]/?A..Z:$_'
```

---

- *update 34* save 12 bytes by omitting `for` and using barewords, thanks to [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings).
- *update 33* save 1 byte using `-E` and `say` instead of `print`.

Comment: @DomHastings Thanks! Should have known barewords were allowed there - and I should've seen that `for` :-/. Tried a bunch of approaches, (`-p` with `$"='';$_="@_"`, even `$a='/[a-z]/?a..z:';print eval$a.uc$a.'$_'` but everything is longer...

Comment: Had a think on this, if you set `$_=` instead of `print`ing and use the `-p` flag instead of `-n` you can save another two... I still can't think of any other ways to save more so far...

Comment: @DomHastings I tried that, but I can't set `$_` to a list (that I know of). It would have to be interpolated (`$_="@_"`) but that uses space as a separator so I'd have to do `$"=''` as well, (or use a `join'',`) which makes it longer.  Not much wiggle room on this one!

Comment: Hah, of course! You even said that (when I re-read the comment after not being at the pub...) I'll keep thinking on it, but you might be the shortest you'll get without using `say` instead of `print`!

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 41 + 1 = 42

With switch `-p`, run

```
([*?A..?z]*'').scan(/\w+/){$&[$_]&&$_=$&}
```

This generates the string

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

and checks each contiguous block of "word characters", which happen to be just the lowercase and uppercase alphabets and the underscore character. If there were multiple consecutive word characters between Z and a, this trick wouldn't work.

**Edited to add explanation, by request:**

The `-p` flag does essentially

```
while( $_ = STDIN.gets )
  #execute code
  print $_
end
```

`[*?A..?z]` is the array of characters between uppercase A and lowercase Z, in ASCII order. That's the uppercase alphabet, some non-letter characters, and the lowercase alphabet. `*''` joins the array into a string, so we can call `.scan` on it. `scan` will find each match of the regular expression `/\w+/`, populate the magic variable `$&` with it, and call the block. Each time the block is iterated, it checks whether the matched string contains `$_` and sets the output to that string if so. So if $_ is contained in either the uppercase or lowercase alphabet, it gets modified accordingly, otherwise it's unchanged.

The ungolfed version would look something like

```
while ($_ = STDIN.gets )
 %w[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz].each do |alphabet|
  $_ = alphabet if alphabet.include?($_)
 end
 print $_
end
```

Comment: Can you post an un-golfed version? I'm still not understanding fully how this works.

Comment: Sure, posted one.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>46</s> 43 characters

(42 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```ruby
[?a..?z,?A..?Z].map{|r|r===$_&&$_=[*r]*""}
```

Thanks to:

- [Jordan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11261/jordan) for the `===` magic (-3 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n 'm' | ruby -pe '[?a..?z,?A..?Z].map{|r|r===$_&&$_=[*r]*""}'
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

bash-4.3$ echo -n 'W' | ruby -pe '[?a..?z,?A..?Z].map{|r|r===$_&&$_=[*r]*""}'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

bash-4.3$ echo -n '@' | ruby -pe '[?a..?z,?A..?Z].map{|r|r===$_&&$_=[*r]*""}'
@
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 18 bytes

```
'[,65>_elr:R]{R&}=
```

`'[,65>` pushes the uppercase alphabet, `_el` the lowercase alphabet, and `r:R` a single-char string that is read from STDIN and assigned to variable `R`. These are wrapped in an array (`]`) and the first one that has any chars in common with `R` is selected using `{R&}=`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to CJam, but I'm lost between the official doc and what I'm reading here. Can someone give me for example a page where I can understand why is `_el` the lowercase alphabet?

Comment: Ah, `el` means "convert to lowercase". I've just pushed the uppercase alphabet, so now I duplicate it with `_`, then call `el` on the resulting copy.

Comment: I made a [nice pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15495351/cjam.pdf) containing (almost) all CJam commands.

Answer (score 4):

## Retina, 62 bytes

```
[a-z]
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
[A-Z]
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

The two short lines are the regex to match. If the input is lowercase (in the range `[a-z]`), it replaces that character (in this case, that is the entire input) with the lowercase alphabet. The process is similar for uppercase. If it's not a letter, no replacements are made, and it is outputted untouched.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=W2Etel0KYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXoKW0EtWl0KQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVo&input=QQpmCj8)

Answer (score 4):

#[MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 22 bytes

```
jtt1Y2XIm~Iw?km?Ik]]1$
```

This uses the [current version (3.1.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/3.1.0) of the language.

*EDIT (Sep 15, 2017): Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=jtt1Y2XIm%7EIw%3Fkm%3FIk%5D%5D1%24&inputs=e&version=20.4.1) (with a newer version of the language).*

###Examples

```
>> matl jtt1Y2XIm~Iw?km?Ik]]1$
> e
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

>> matl jtt1Y2XIm~Iw?km?Ik]]1$
> T
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

>> matl jtt1Y2XIm~Iw?km?Ik]]1$
> "
"
```

###Explanation

```
j              % input string (assumed to be a single character)        
tt             % duplicate twice
1Y2            % predefined literal: uppercase letters
XI             % copy to clipboard I         
m~             % check if not member    
I              % paste from clipboard I      
w              % swap elements in stack      
?              % if
    k          % convert string to lowercase 
    m          % check if member         
    ?          % if                          
        I      % paste from clipboard I      
        k      % convert string to lowercase 
    ]          % end                         
]              % end                         
1$             % input specification for implicit printing
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2.7.10, <s>95</s> <s>93</s> 79 bytes

This is my first time even attempting to golf, so please, any help or advice is extremely appreciated!

```
from string import* 
lambda i:(i,(uppercase,lowercase)[i.islower()])[i.isalpha()]
```

Thanks to Morgan Thrapp for the help!

Comment: @MorganThrapp, that doesn't seem to work. Are you sure that it works in Python 2.7.10?

Comment: It works in 2.7.8. What doesn't work?

Comment: @MorganThrapp, actually, could you please explain first exactly how that works? Maybe it's just that I don't understand so I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Sure, it uses the fact that `False == 0` and `True == 1` to index into tuples. So, it first checks if it's a letter with `isalpha`, if it is, it returns `1` and then checks if it's lowercase and does the same.

Comment: @MorganThrapp, oh wow. That's pretty cool. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I love golfing, so I'm always happy to help out someone new!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33347/discussion-between-morgan-thrapp-and-dopapp).

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, <s>98</s> 97 bytes

Sadly, I didn't find a solution shorter than 26 bytes to set `a` with the alphabet. In fact, I didn't find shorter than 32.

**Edit : save 1 Byte thanks to @ATaco, was doing this error a lot when started with Lua :p**

```lua
c=io.read()a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz"print(not c:find"%a"and c or c:find"%u"and a:upper()or a)
```

You can test it online on the [official site](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) or on [ideone](http://ideone.com/). If you use the former, the input won't work (disabled), so use the following source, where it is wrapped into a function.

```lua
function f(c)
  a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz"
  print(not c:find"%a"and c or c:find"%u"and a:upper()or a)
end

print(f("\""))
print(f("a"))
print(f("Q"))
```

Comment: You are not the only who [not found shorter way](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40051) to generate the alphabet in Lua. :(

Comment: @manatwork haha, exactly the same thing, except I didn't have to print it, but to concatenate it ^^. At least, that mean there isn't a hidden trick I didn't know to do it ^^'.

Comment: You can save a byte with `c=io.read()a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz"` instead of a,c=...

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 23 bytes

Includes +2 for `-nE` (instead of the normal +1) to be fair to the other perl solution

Run with the input on STDIN without trailing newline:

```
echo -n g | perl -lnE 'say/\pL/?a&$_|A..Z:$_'
```

Just the code:

```
say/\pL/?a&$_|A..Z:$_
```

Comment: Nice use of the fact that input is limited to 7-bit characters.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 9 bytes

```
;[CBU]æøU
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O1tDQlVd5vhV&input=Imgi)

Answer (score 3):

## C (gcc), 91 bytes

A function that accepts a `char` and prints the result via stdout (91 bytes):

```c
f(x){puts(isalpha(x)?x>90?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":&x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KzuqC0pFgjszgxpyAjEci3r7CzNLBXSkxKTklNS8/IzMrOyc3LLygsKi4pLSuvqKxSslJydHJ2cXVz9/D08vbx9fMPCAwKDgkNC4@IjFKyUqvQtK79n5uYmaehWZ2ckVikUKFgq5CeWgJia2haK4AsBapIBAA)

Bonus (a shorter version of `MD XF`'s answer, since I don't have enough reputation to comment (90 bytes):)

```c
#define f(x)isalpha(x)?x>90?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":&x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU2jQjOzODGnICMRyLKvsLM0sFdKTEoGSqdnZGZl5@Tm5RcUFhWXlJaVV1RWKVkpOTo5u7i6uXt4enn7@Pr5BwQGBYeEhoVHREYpWalV/M9NzMzT0KxOzkgsUqhQsFVITy0BsTU0rRUKSkuKNUAWalrX/k8EAA)

Comment: You now have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 2):

## SpecBAS, 111 bytes

I've been through several versions of this, 111 seems to be the best I can manage.

```
1 INPUT l$: a$="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
2  ?IIF$(l$ IN ["a" TO "z","A" TO "Z"],IIF$(l$=UP$ l$,UP$ a$,a$),l$)
```

Line 2 uses the `?` shortcut for `PRINT` and nested inline `IF` statements

Pseudo code explanation

```
IF character IN "a".."z","A".."Z"
THEN
 IF character = UPPERCASE character
 THEN
  print UPPERCASE alphabet
 ELSE
  print alphabet
 ENDIF
ELSE
 print the character
ENDIF
```

Comment: It's hard to make `["a" TO "z","A" TO "Z"]` look more like a pseudo code than it already does. `"a".."z","A".."Z"` looks more like a "real code", at least in my eyes... Both are very easy to understand though =)

Comment: Spec _what_????

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 75 bytes

```
#/.Thread[Join[a=Alphabet[],b=ToUpperCase@a]->Array[""<>If[#>26,b,a]&,52]]&
```

Pretty good score for a non-golfing language... Any solutions using character code processing would take more bytes, due to the costs of `ToCharacterCode` and `FromCharacterCode`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 81 bytes

```python
f=lambda z,a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":[k for k in[a,a.upper(),z]if z in k][0]
```

This is basically a translation of the Pyth answer. It defines a function `f` that takes as argument the character and returns the result.

Comment: You mean `if z in k`, right? Also, `f=` is optional by default.

Comment: @xnor Yes. Apparently I missed a Ctrl-C.

Comment: Remove `f=`, make the function anonymous. -2

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB: <s>71</s> 68 bytes

```
i=input('');b=i<65|i>122|(i>90&i<97);[i*b,~b*((65:90)+32*(i>96)),'']
```

(thanks to OP for saving 3 bytes)

Test:

```
i='a'
ans=
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

i='A'
ans=
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

i='~'
ans=
~
```

Explanation:
Uppercase alphabet occupies `65:90` ASCII characters. Lowercase alphabet is at `97:122` ASCII. So, `b=i<65|i>122|(i>90&i<97)` checks whether the input character `i` is NOT alphabetic. If so, input is returned. The uppercase alphabet is returned if `b==1` and `i<97` (uppercase character). If `b==1` and `i>96`, 32 is added to `65:90` that corresponds to `97:122` - the lowercase alphabet.

Comment: Nice submission. Two comments: It's common to either use `i=input('')` if the submission is a script, or as a function argument if it's a function `@(i)i^2`. `i='a'` is in general not accepted. Also, you can save 3 bytes by doing `[1,2,3,'']` instead of `char([1,2,3])`.

Comment: Ok, edited. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 2, 142 Bytes

```
func d(s:String)->String{let a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";for v in s.utf8{return v>64&&v<91 ?a.uppercaseString:(v>96&&v<123 ?a:s)};return s}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
func d(s: String) -> String{
    let a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for v in s.utf8{
        return (
            v > 64 && v < 91 ?
            a.uppercaseString :
            (
                v > 96 && v < 123 ?
                a :
                s
            )
        )
     }
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C (function), 71 bytes

```
f(s,n,c){n=1;if(isalpha(s))s-=s%32-1,n=26;for(c=s;c<s+n;)putchar(c++);}
```

Comment: `f(s,n,c){for(c=s-=(n=isalpha(s)?26:1)>1?s%32-1:0;c<s+n;)putchar(c++);}` saves a byte.

Comment: `f(s,n){for(n=isalpha(s)?s-=s%32-1,s+26:s+1;s<n;)putchar(s++);}` for 62 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/), 17 bytes

[Try it here.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=PyBocExpcGw_IGhwVWlwdWk&input=RgoKegoKIgoKIA)

```
? hpLipl? hpUipui
?                  if
  hpL               the lowercase alphabet (array) contains
     i               the input
      pl            return the lowercase alphabet (string)
        ?          else if
          hpU       the uppercase alphabet (array) contains
             i       the input
              pu    return the uppercase alphabet (string)
                i  otherwise, return the input
                   implicit: print the result
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 165 characters

```
class A {public static void main(String[]p){int c=p[0].charAt(0),d=c|32,b=(d-96)*(d-123),e=b<0?65|(c&32):c,f=e+(b<0?26:1);for(;e<f;e++){System.out.print((char)e);}}}
```

Generates the required output to stdout (rather than returning it).
Input is via the runtime arguments.

How it works.

1) Setup some integer variables
c = the ASCII value of the first character of the first parameter of the runtime arguments.
d = c converted to lowercase ASCII value (by ORing it with 32)
b = calculation to see if d is a letter. Will be <0 if a letter.
e = The start character for output. If ASCII value in d is a letter (see b) then it is set to 'A' (or 'a' by adding c AND 32 to 'A' ASCII value) else it is set to the original value of c.
f = the number of characters to output. If it not a letter (see b) then this is set to 1 else it is set to 26
2) Loop from e to e+f outputing each character to stdout.

Comment: You know that for most challenges the solution can be provided either as complete program or a function? Given the enormous amount of boilerplate code in Java, a function may be shorter.

Comment: Applying a couple of small tricks, without changing the logic, I got this: `void f(char c){for(int d=c|32,b=(d-96)*(d-123),e=b<0?65|(c&32):c,f=e+(b<0?26:1);e<f;)System.out.print((char)e++);}`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> 16 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to `else`

```
DAsåiAëDAusåiAuë
```

How it works

```
                   # implicit input
D                  # duplicate
 A                 # push lowercase alphabet
  s                # swap last two elements
   å               # push a in b
    i              # if
     A             # lowercase alphabet
      ë            # else
         D         # duplicate
          Au       # uppercase alphabet
            s      # swap last two elements
             å     # push a in b
              I    # if
               Au  # uppercase alphabet
                 ë # else leave input
                   # implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fxbH48NJMx8OrXRxLwazSw6v//08EAA)

Comment: Not sure if `¹` (first input) already existed when you posted your answer, but you can golf 2 bytes with it: `A¹åiAëAu¹åiAuë` ([Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8dDOw0szHQ@vdiyFsEoPr/7/PxUA) or [test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkv1/x8rDSzMdD692LAUzSg@v/l9ZW6vzP5XLm8uUywEA)).

Comment: I think you can leave out the last `ë` since that's implicit

Answer (score 2):

### Java SE 8, <s>71</s> 69 bytes

Golfed:

```
(a,s)->{char b=97;if(a<91)b-=32;a=b;b+=26;while(a<b)s+=a++;return s;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
(a,s)->{          // String as a parameter. If declaration is necessary it adds 8 bytes
char b = 97;      // Uppercase A char, this is important
if (a < 91)       // If it is not past 'z', where a is a char param
    b -= 32;      // Then go back to the lowercase alphabet
a = b;            // Done to prevent a cast
b += 26;          // End of alphabet
while (a < b)     // Go to end of alphabet
    s += a++;     // Append character
return s;}        // Then return
```

I had originally implemented the following

```
String s="";char b=96;if(a-91<0)b-=32;for(char c=b;++c<b+27;)s+=c;return s;
```

It's more elegant but sadly it's one byte larger. This is assuming that behavior for non alpha characters is undefined and string s is initialized to "" prior to execution. Be gentle it's my first post.

edit: 2 bytes saved by Stewie Griffin by changing

```
a - 91 < 0 to a < 91
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Thanks! Been lurking for a few years now and really interested to see if I can make competing Java/C++ answers :)

Comment: `a<91` should work, or...?

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 91 characters

```
(c:Char)=>{var a='a'.to('z').mkString;if(c.isUpper)a=a.toUpperCase;if(!c.isLetter)a=""+c;a}
```

### Un-golfed

```
def f(c: Char): String = {
    var a='a'.to('z').mkString //set up lower case default response
    if (c.isUpper) {
        a = a.toUpperCase     //mutate the result if upper case
    }        
    if (!c.isLetter) { 
      a = ""+c                 //mutate the result if not a letter
    }
    a                         //return result
}
```

Having a initial mutable result rather than returning an immutable value from 3 distinct if else blocks saved me 2 chars, even though I hate it.

### Scala-thonic method

A better method for scala would be something like this:

```
def convertToAlphabet(c: Char): String = {
    c match {
      case x if !x.isLetter => x.toString
      case x if x.isUpper => ('A' to 'Z').mkString
      case _ => ('a' to 'z').mkString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
∈Ạ|ḷ∈Ạụ|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bG04vK/z/q6Hi4a0HNwx3bIayHu5fW/P8freSmpKNUBcQxSkBCQSkWAA)

```
∈Ạ          The input is a member of the lowercase alphabet,
  |         which is output, or
   ḷ∈Ạ      the input lowercased is a member of the lowercase alphabet,
      ụ|    which is output uppercased, or the input is output.
```

It'd be two bytes shorter if we had a constant for the uppercase alphabet but we don't :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-ir` <s>45</s> <s>37</s> 21 bytes

```
:AZ"•[_AZɧ|:az"•[_azɧ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fyjFK6VHDouh4x6iTy2usEqsgvMSqk8v///f9r5tZBAA)

*-16 bytes due to using ranges*

### Answer History

#### 37 bytes

```
::`>$\~<*[_z(|:;)^|:A1->[_Z(|:;)^|,
```

-8 bytes thanks to A__

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fyirBTiWmzkYrOr5KQ7LGylozrsbK0VDXLjo@CsbX@f8/FwA)

Comment: [37B](https://tio.run/##y05N///fyirBTiWmzkYrOr5KQ7LGylozrsbK0VDXLjo@CsbX@f8/FwA) by using control characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
aNz?zaNAZ?AZa
```

builtins.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0a/KvirRzzHK3jEq8f///44A)

Comment: Is this a reference to sporeball's esolang?!?!?!

Comment: without a doubt

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
Ǎ[æ[kA|ka
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%8D%5B%C3%A6%5BkA%7Cka&inputs=X&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
           # Implicit input
Ǎ[         # If input is a letter:
  æ[       #   If input is capitalized:
    kA     #     Push 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
      |    #   Else:
       ka  #     Push 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
aN_FI[zAZ]|a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0S/ezTO6yjEqtibx////ygA)

[Razetime's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210560/16766) is the approach I thought of too, but 13 bytes seemed rather long. So I went looking for other approaches...

```
     [zAZ]    List containing the lowercase alphabet and the uppercase alphabet
   FI         Filter on this function:
aN_            Is the command-line argument in each string?
              If the argument is lowercase, the result is the lowercase alphabet*; if
              it's uppercase, the result is the uppercase alphabet*; and if it's
              neither, the result is an empty list, so...
          |a  Logical OR with the argument: if filter result is [], print arg instead

* As a single-element list, but without flags, that doesn't affect how it is displayed
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.8, <del>108</del> 93 bytes

-15 bytes thanks to Aaron Miller

```python
a='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
print(a if(x:=input())in a else a.lower()if x.islower()else x)
```

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##LckxDsIwDAXQvafwmDB0YUFIHTgJsioHvtQmlu2KcPqAEOPT03c8Wz1f1MYo1nbyMNQHYddmcZp4YV@B@6EqtrLLpN@PxISS@nVB1SNSzqjEJJsL8by1l1jKKNRn@F@/63mM2wc "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Scratch that, [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9FW3dHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjJKnaugKDOvRCNRITNNo8LKNjOvoLREQ1MzM08hUSE1pzhVIVEvJ788tUhDMzNNoUIvsxjKA8tVaP7/7wgA)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 111 bytes

```
Input Str1
"inString(Ans,Str1→u
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
If u
Stop
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
If u
Stop
Str1
```

Output is stored in `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 60 characters

```
\A=@set{a;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
<J>=$a
<K>=@upcase{$a}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@set{a;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz};<J>=$a;<K>=@upcase{$a}' <<< 'm'
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@set{a;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz};<J>=$a;<K>=@upcase{$a}' <<< 'W'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@set{a;abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz};<J>=$a;<K>=@upcase{$a}' <<< '@'
@
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda c,i=26:c[c.isalpha():]or c*i and f(c,i-1)+chr(i^ord(c)&96)
```

For letter inputs, generates the string of letters recursively. Doing `ord(c)&96` removes the 5 high bits, and the xor'ing the values `i` from 1 to 26 gives the letter char codes. For control flow, we count `i` down, adding new letters to the end, stopping when `i=0`. When the input `c` is not a letter, immediately outputs it and stops.

Thanks to Mauris for 2 bytes.

Previous solution (68):

```python
lambda c:[c,str(bytearray(range(ord(c)&96,255)[1:27]))][c.isalpha()]
```

Comment: *The input will be any of the printable ASCII characters from 32 to 126 (space to tilde).* Wouldn't `ord(c)&96` suffice, then?

Comment: @Mauris Yes, good call.

Comment: I think `'_'` --> `c` works and saves a byte in your recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Sed, 61 characters

(60 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```
s/[a-z]/&abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/i
s/[A-Z].*/\U&/
T
s/.//
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ sed -r 's/[a-z]/&abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/i;s/[A-Z].*/\U&/;T;s/.//' <<< 'm'
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

bash-4.3$ sed -r 's/[a-z]/&abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/i;s/[A-Z].*/\U&/;T;s/.//' <<< 'W'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

bash-4.3$ sed -r 's/[a-z]/&abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/i;s/[A-Z].*/\U&/;T;s/.//' <<< '@'
@
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 88 bytes (incl. print)

```
from string import*
def f(c):print[c,uppercase,c,lowercase,c][sorted('@Z`z'+c).index(c)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>99</s> <s>87</s> <s>79</s> 78 bytes

```
x=>(y='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',parseInt(x,36)>9?x>'`'?y:y.toUpperCase():x)
```

<s>Uses the [short array fill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61505/30793) trick to allocate space, then just math and `String.fromCharCode` to get the alphabet.</s> Thought it would be shorter until I realized the rule about non-alphabet characters. `parseInt` turned out to be helpful in determining if the character was in the alphabet.

### Test

```js
var F=x=>(y='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',parseInt(x,36)>9?x>'`'?y:y.toUpperCase():x)
```

```html
x = <input type="text" oninput="result.textContent=this.value?F(this.value):''" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: `x=>parseInt(x,36,y='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')>9?x>{}?y:y.toUpperCase():x`

Answer (score 1):

## [Mouse-2002](http://github.com/catb0t/mouse15/), 125 bytes

... or 126 bytes if I can't assume a REPL envrironment (which assumes a `$` at the end of the program; the non-REPL interpreter crashes without one)

An attempt at code deduplication... probably a failed one.

Golfed:

```
?'a:123b:a.65<a.31>*1=a.90>a.97<*1=+a.122>+1=[a.!']a.63>a.91<*1=[65i:(i.91<^i.!'i.1+i:)]a.96>a.b.<*1=[97i:(i.b.<^i.!'i.1+i:)]
```

Ungolfed:

```
?' a:                    ~ a = getchar();
123 b:                   ~ b = 123
a. 65 <                  ~ return whether a < 65
a. 31 >                  ~ same for 31
  * 1 =                    ~ AND
a. 90 >                  ~ a > 90 ?
a. 97 <                  ~ a < 97 ?
  * 1 =                    ~ AND
+                          ~ OR
a.122 >                  ~ a > 122 ?
  + 1 =                    ~ OR
[                          ~ if 1
  a.!'                       ~ print ascii codepoint
]                          ~ fi
a. 63 >                  ~ a > 63 ?
a. 91 <                  ~ a < 91 ?
  * 1 =                    ~ AND
[                          ~ if 1
  65 i:                      ~ for i = 65;
  (                          ~ do;
    i. 91 < ^                  ~ i < 91;
    i.!'                       ~ print(charAt(i));
    i. 1+ i:                   ~ i++;
  )                         ~ done;
]                          ~ fi
a. 96 >                  ~ a > 96 ?
a. b. <                  ~ a < b ?
  * 1 =                    ~ AND
[                          ~ if 1
  97 i:                      ~ for i = 97;
  (                          ~ do;
    i. b. < ^                  ~ i < 91; 
    i.!'                       ~ print(charAt(i));
    i. 1+ i:                   ~ i++;
  )                          ~ done;
]                          ~ fi
$                        ~ \bye
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 56+2 = 58 bytes

2 bytes for `-p` flag

```ruby
c=$_[0]
[?a..?z,?A..?Z].map{|r|r===c&&c=r.to_a.join}
p c
```

Ungolfed version (no `-p` flag)

```ruby
while true
  char = gets.chars.first
  [("a".."z"),("A".."Z")].each do |range|
    char = range.to_a.join("") if range.include? char
  end
  p char
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [s-lang](http://dgrissom.com/s-lang/), 40 bytes (non-competing)

Replaces any letter with the alphabet, matching the case.

```
t@[[a-z]][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]
```

- t Replace with regex function
- @ Match case for entire match parameter for t function
- [[a-z]] first argument ([a-z]) regex for matching any letter (@ parameter makes it so this function ignores the case when matching, so we don't need A-Z too)
- abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz what to replace it with

### [Try it here](http://dgrissom.com/s-lang/?t@[[a-z]][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])

Answer (score 1):

### Java 7, 99 bytes

```
void f(char c){for(int a=c|32,i=97;i<123;i++)System.out.print(a<123&a>96?(char)(i-a+c):i<98?c:"");}
```

Slightly more readable, with no scrollbars:

```
void f(char c){
    for(int a=c|32,i=97;i<123;i++)  // a is lowercased input, i loops alphabet 
        System.out.print(           
            a<123&a>96?             // if a is a letter
                (char)(i-a+c):      //   subtract diff between lower and input
                    i<98?c:"");     // else print input if first iteration
}
```

The logic here is pretty straightforward, but a different method than the [other Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67496/14215).

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 50

```
{join "",/<:Lu>/??"A".."Z"!!/<:Ll>/??"a".."z"!!$_}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 60 bytes

```php
for(ctype_alpha($c=$argn)?$c=$c&a|A:$z=25;$z++<26;)echo$c++;
```

Run as pipe with `-R`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 13 bytes

```
||&N(a(&N)a)a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/pkbNTyNRQ81PM1ETyFXXUgcA)

## Explanation:

This roughly translates to `'N(a and (' or 'N)a and )' or a`. `N(a` checks if `a` is in `(`. `(` and `)` are upper and lower-case alphabet yield.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 32 bytes

```
"AZ"Ris~[p&o;]&p"az"Rl~[p&o;]lo;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/1/JMUopKLO4LrpALd86Vq1AKbFKKSgHys3Jt/7/3xEA)

Explanation:

```
"AZ"Ris~[p&o;]&p"az"Rl~[p&o;]lo;

     is                          # take input and save it
"AZ"R  ~[    ]                   # is it in the uppercase alphabet?
         p&o;                    # output the stack, terminate
              &p                 # clear stack
                     l           # load input
                "az"R ~[    ]    # is it in the lowercase alphabet?
                        p&o;     # output the stack, terminate
                             lo; # output the input, terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
c=ord(input())
print[chr(c),bytearray(range(c&96|1,c&96|27))][64<c&95<91]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9k2vyhFIzOvoLREQ1OTq6AoM68kOjmjSCNZUyepsiQ1sagosVKjKDEvPVUjWc3SrMZQB0wZmWtqxkabmdgAeaY2loax//@rh6kDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```apl
t←{⍵∊g←819⌶f←⎕A:g⋄⍵∊f:f⋄⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@RR24TqR71bH3V0pQOZFoaWj3q2pQFZj/qmOlqlP@pugUimWaVB2LVAPeqJ6lwl6o4gQglEAAFXiYIhAA)

The byte count does not include `t←` because it's not *necessary*, it just assigns the function to `t` (so you can call it by using `t input`).

If input is not a number, it needs to be enclosed in single quotes. For the input `'`, you need to escape it by typing it twice (so the call is `t ''''`)

Thanks to @Adám for 2 bytes.

#### How it works:

```apl
{⍵∊g←819⌶f←⎕A:g⋄⍵∊f:f⋄⍵} ⍝ Main function
             :            ⍝ if
         f←⎕A             ⍝ Assigns the uppercase alphabet to f
   g←819⌶                 ⍝ Assigns the I-Beam command 819 (case convert) over the uppercase alphabet (f) to g
 ⍵∊                       ⍝ The right argument 'is in' the lowercase alphabet
              g           ⍝ then print g (the lowercase alphabet)
               ⋄   :      ⍝ else if
                ⍵∊f       ⍝ the right argument 'is in' f (the uppercase alphabet)           
                    f     ⍝ print f
                     ⋄⍵   ⍝ else, print the right argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

Unnamed prefix lambda.

```apl
{⊃a/⍨⍵∊¨a←⎕A(819⌶⎕A)⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@RR24TqR13NifqPelc86t36qKPr0IpEoOCjvqmOGhaGlo96toGYmkC5WqBy9UR1rhJ1RxChBCKAgKtEwRAA)

`{`…`}` anonymous function where `⍵` represents the argument:

`⎕A(819⌶⎕A)⍵` uppercase **A**lphabet, lowercased **A**lphabet, argument

`a←` store in `a` (for **a**ll)

`⍵∊¨` three Booleans for argument's membership of each those

`a/⍨` filter `a` by that

`⊃` pick the first

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), 94 bytes

```
#define f(c)isupper(c)?"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":islower(c)?"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":&c
```

`#define f(c)` is like declaring a function `f` that takes a variable `c`.

`isupper(c)` checks if `c` is an uppercase letter, returns the uppercase alphabet if so. Otherwise, it checks if it's lowercase. If so, it returns the lowercase alphabet. Otherwise, it returns a pointer to `c`, which can be printed as a string (since you must pass a `char` or `int` to `f`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU0jWTOzuLSgILUIyLJXcnRydnF1c/fw9PL28fXzDwgMCg4JDQuPiIxSssoszskvh6pLTEoGmpCekZmVnZObl19QWFRcUlpWXlFZpWSllvw/NzEzT0OzOjOvRCHZNj21JDkjsUhD07qgtKRYA2SlpnXtf0cA)

Comment: Is it possible to store the alphabet in a variable and use `toupper` in here (I don't know C)

Comment: @StewieGriffin `toupper` only works on `char`s, and `strtoupper`/`strupper` is not standard C (nor implemented on many systems).

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 80 bytes

```r
s=(r=65:90)+32
a=utf8ToInt(scan(,''));intToUtf8("if"(a%in%r,r,"if"(a%in%s,s,a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9hWo8jWzNTK0kBT29iIK9G2tCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR11dU9M6M68kJD8UKKOhlJmmpJGompmnWqRTpIPgFesU6yRqamr@L/8PAA)

-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe. Still not the golfiest way ([see here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86271/80010)). Similar ideas include:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 87 bytes

```r
f=function(x,y)"if"(a%in%x,x,y)
a=utf8ToInt(scan(,''));intToUtf8(f(r<-65:90,f(r+32,a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP0@jQqdSUykzTUkjUTUzT7VCB8TnSrQtLUmzCMn3zCvRKE5OzNPQUVfX1LTOzCsJyQ8FymikaRTZ6JqZWlka6ACZ2sZGOomampr/Vf4DAA)

```r
a=utf8ToInt(scan(,''));intToUtf8("if"(a%in%c(32:64,91:96,123:126),a,65:90+32*(a>90)))
```

and my favorite:

```r
a=utf8ToInt(scan(,''));intToUtf8(c(a,65:90+32*(a>90))[2*a%in%c(32:64,91:96,123:126)-1])
```

and inspired by the other R solution (same bytecount):

```r
"+"=function(x,y)"if"(a%in%x,x,y)
a=scan(,'');cat(letters+LETTERS+a,sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X0lbyTatNC@5JDM/T6NCp1JTKTNNSSNRNTNPtUIHxOdKtC1OTszT0FFX17ROTizRyEktKUktKtb2cQ0JcQ0K1k7UKU4tsFVS0vzv8x8A)

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9hWo8jWzNTK0kBT29iIK9G2tCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR11dU9M6M68kJD8UKKOhlJmmpJGompmnWqRTpIPgFesU6yRqamr@L/8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Noether, 40 bytes

```
{0A~bI~a/~c}{bP}b{Ua/~d}{bUP}1{cd|-}{aP}
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=ezBBfmJJfmEvfmN9e2JQfWJ7VWEvfmR9e2JVUH0xe2NkfC19e2FQfQ&input=Ikci)

Uses Noether's built-in constant function `A` to return the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx`.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 193 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){var z="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";var b=a[0];System.Console.Write(b.Length>1?b:z.IndexOf((b[0]))>-1?z:z.ToLower().IndexOf((b[0]))>-1?z.ToLower():b[0]+"");}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##bYvNCoIwAIBfRTxthFJXJaU/y9KstKzEw1yrBraBG1ZGz77s1KXr94OFgQVWCpdICG31EhJJirWa05MWIsqAkBVllyxH8FWjSmv6@mA4Gk@86cyfL4JwGa3WmzjZ7tL94ajb36Too6yb2/FTSHIzR5wJXhIzragkoDADwi7y6vTcwmpMn53IIzoDULQHhI7Rc5sWJzzgd1IB@Df4aetLO7oO7fdbKeV9AA) EDIT: Variable assignment with if statements is stupid

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 75 bytes

```sh
l=${(j::):-{a..z}} u=$l:u
<<<${${${l:#*$1*}:+${${${u:#*$1*}:+$1}:-$u}}:-$l}
```

---

```sh
l=${(j::):-{a..z}}                                  # set l to the (j::)oined lowercase
                   u=$l:u                           # set u to :uppercase'd l
<<<${${${l:#*$1*}:+${${${u:#*$1*}:+$1}:-$u}}:-$l}
       ${l:#*$1*}                                   # remove *$1* from $l (is empty if $1 is lower)
     ${          :+                        }        # If non-empty, then...
                       ${u:#*$1*}                   # remove *$1* from $u (is empty if $1 is upper)
                     ${          :+$1}              # If non-empty, substitute $1
                   ${                 :-$u}         # If empty, substitute $u
    ${                                       :-$l}  # If empty, substitute $l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTquDpFmyrUJSamKJQYa2Qks9VnFqioKuroFLxP8dWpVojy8pK00q3OlFPr6q2VqHUViXHqpTLxsZGpRoEc6yUtVQMtWqttCH8UgTfsNZKV6W0FkTm1P5Pyc9L/Z/I5chVxRXFpcilwFXHBQA)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcqxDsIgEADQ/b7ibG5QE4auQJu4mDi7uSFcrAYLoTU2tPXXsfN7eejKwGOII96TsWyth2/39IyX87XBxMbhpNAF2BYKgTRBeuOx@Ibm/UvKgxSzEXldlda6Ig/k5adq26geiSNSjXFZNqK6uNBzMXCCDDfYAcIP/g) using grep

Comment: Nice! Post that as a Zsh+coreutils answer if you want, I'll keep this as a pure Zsh answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 84 bytes

```python
lambda x,a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':[x,a,a.upper()][(x in a)+2*(x in a.upper())]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ9FWPTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJK3SoaqEInUa@0oCC1SEMzNlqjQiEzTyFRU9tIC8qEyWnG/i8oyswr0UjTUHdT19TkgvOqUHhKKDwFIO8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>62</s> 49 bytes

```
#/.(#|##->""<>##&)@@@{A=Alphabet[],Capitalize@A}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcfBCoIwGADg@55i/D9IwcwXyLEhCN2Cuq0dVswcOB3yd9F89pWXD77oqPfRUXi53NUZq9MBv4ilBDhLxOKolFp1rYfUu6cnY0XjUiA3hMUrvRX5OoeRDPJS8vt0o//eplMoLmP6UDvN0dqiUiuDFgSDZecBuxzYln8)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 93 bytes

```
i=input();a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";A=a.upper();print(i in a and a or i in A and A or i)
```

Under 100 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## C - 65 Bytes

```
f(c){for(c=islower(c)?97:c>64&c<91?65:c;(putchar(c++)|32)<122;);}
```

Thanks to @ceilingcat for -5 bytes

**Ungolfed (original version)**

```
i = 65;

f(c)
{
    if(isalpha(c))
        while(i < 91)
            putchar(c & 32 | i++); 
    else
        putchar(c);
}
```

**Explanation**

A function that receives an integer (the input character) and prints it if it is not a letter or prints the entire alphabet with the capitalization of the input character.

Answer (score 0):

### Seriously, 17 bytes

```
    ;;ú(úíuIúû;(@íuI
```

Hex Dump:

```
093b3ba328a3a17549a3963b2840a17549
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=093b3ba328a3a17549a3963b2840a17549&input=g)

Given that it pretty much just reads in an unformatted byte, checks if it's in the lowercase alphabet, then checks if it's in the uppercase alphabet, the automatic documentation given in the link is sufficient. (Note, however, that the documentation for `í` has the argument order reversed; it pops the sequence first.)

Answer (score 0):

### k4, 24 bytes

```
{*b@&x in/:b:(.Q`A`a),x}
```

Another port of the Pyth answer—constructs a list of upper, lower, and the arg, and returns the first one that contains the arg.

Answer (score 0):

## [Sprects](https://dinod123.neocities.org/interpreter.html), 207 bytes

```
|<CHAR>|ZA|YA|XA|WA|VA|UA|TA|SA|RA|QA|PA|OA|NA|MA|LA|KA|JA|IA|HA|GA|FA|EA|DA|CA|BA|AABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ|za|ya|xa|wa|va|ua|ta|sa|ra|qa|pa|oa|na|ma|la|ka|ja|ia|ha|ga|fa|ea|da|ca|ba|aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Enter character on `<CHAR>`.

Answer (score 0):

## AWK 104 bytes

```
/[a-z]/{print"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}
/[A-Z]/{print"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}
/[^A-z]/{print$0}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 116 bytes

```
$b='j';$a='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';switch($b){{$b-cmatch'[a-z]'}{$a.ToLower()}{$b-cmatch'[A-Z]'}{$a}default{$_}}
```

Change `$b='j'` to modify result.

I couldn't figure out a way to get the alphabet that was shorter than just writing the alphabet unfortunately.

e.g. `(65..90|%{[char][byte]$_})-join''`

Comment: This appears to be whats called a snippet program, where input is taken from a variable, in this case `b`.  Snippets are not allowed so you should restructure to either a function or a full program.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG! Take a look at [New users' guide to PowerShell](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11938/42963) and [Tips for golfing in Windows PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/191/42963) to get some basics. Secondly, to get the alphabet shorter, try `-join[char[]](65..90)` for 21 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 114 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
a=Asc([A1]):i=IIf(a>64And a<91,64,(a>96And a<123)*-96):?IIf(i=0,[A1],"");:If i>0 Then For j=1To 26:?Chr(i+j);:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 75 bytes

```
b=arg(1)
a=xrange(a,z)
if b>z then a=lower(a)
if verify(b,a) then a=b
say a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
XØA,Øa¤ċÐfȯ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//WMOYQSzDmGHCpMSLw5BmyK////8nIic)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 103 bytes

```
VAR u="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
VAR l="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
=o(c)
{u?c:{u}|{l?c:{l}|{c}}}->->
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/q9rl6@h5KakqWv3P8wxSKHUVsnRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIySokLpCTHVikxKTklNS09IzMrOyc3L7@gsKi4pLSsvKKySonLNl8jWZOrutQ@2aq6tLamOgfEyAEykmtra3XtgPb8BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
AsAus©åiAuë®åiAë®
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fsdixtPjQysNLMx1LD68@tA7EANFAGQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVulir6TwqG2SgpL9f8dix9LiQysPL810LD28@tA6EANE/6@srdX578ZVxaXEpQAA).

```
                   # (implicit) push STDIN to stack
A                  # push "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 s                 # swap top two values of stack
  Au               # push "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    s              # swap top two values of stack
     ©             # store top of stack in register_c
      åi           # if top of stack in second-to-top of stack...
        Au         # push "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
          ë®åi     # elif value of register_c in second-to-top of stack...
              A    # push "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
               ë   # else...
                ®  # push value of register_c
                   # (implicit) output top of stack to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 17 bytes

```
ĐĐʊɔ?ĉʊ:ŕɫɔ?ĉɫ:ŕ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQjE051nZxif6TzVJfV0aknV4PZJ1cD2db//4cDAA)

```
ĐĐ                     implicit input; duplicate twice on stack
  ʊɔ?ĉʊ:               is it a lowercase letter? if so, push lowercase letters
        ŕɫɔ?ĉɫ:        else is it an uppercase letter? if so, push uppercase letters
               ŕ       otherwise, leave input on stack
                ;      end if-then-else statements; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/)*+coreutils, 45 bytes

```sh
l=${(j::):-{a-z}};<<<"$l
$l:u"|grep $1||<<<$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxDoIwEADQ/b7iJDfo0IG1lMHFhNmNrbYX0VwsKRhIKf56ZX15aRrKxHMYZ3xE69g5gWV4CWN3u7cY2XpcG/QBjoVKIa1FWtrOb60vWm1WpX1vjDEVCZDob5WfkUekOudDqS4@fLhYuEKCHk6A8IM/)

(*) Using `setopt braceccl` to save 1 byte

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
A?fh?kA:Ạ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWqx3t0zLssx2tHu5asKQ4KbkYKr5gYQSEAQA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ẠD$Ƈ?:RD$Ƈ?:$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWGx_uWuCicqzd3ioIQqksKU5KLobKLlgYAWEAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
A?fh?kA:Ạ  # Implicit input
A?         # If it's alphabetic:
  fh?      #  If it's uppercase:
     kA    #   Push the uppercase alphabet
       :   #  Otherwise:
        Ạ  #   Push the lowercase alphabet
           # Otherwise, the input remains on top
           # Implicit output
```

```python
ẠD$Ƈ?:RD$Ƈ?:$  # Implicit input
ẠD             # Push the lowercase alphabet and duplicate
  $Ƈ           # Pop one copy and check if the input is in it
    ?          # If it is, do nothing, leaving the lowercase alphabet
               # on the top of the stack to be implicitly output
     :         # Otherwise:
      RD       #  Push the uppercase alphabet and duplicate
        $Ƈ     #  Pop one copy and check if the input is in it
          ?    #  If it is, do nothing, leaving the uppercase alphabet
               #  on the top of the stack to be implicitly output
           :$  #  Otherwise, push the input
               # Implicit output of top of stack
```