# Print the Russian Cyrillic alphabet

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

[Apparently](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/output-the-hebrew-alphabet), we [really like](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97049/print-the-greek-alphabet) printing [the alphabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67357/output-the-alphabet-the-alphabet-or-just-a-character) in different languages.

How about the Russian Cyrillic alphabet?

Print/output/return this exact text (trailing whitespace is permitted)

```
АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя
```

This is the Russian Cyrillic alphabet with upper and lower case interleaved (eg `AaBbCc...`)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so crunch those bytes folks!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer This Unicode order of these make for a very different challenge.

Comment: Is outputting an array of individual characters permitted?

Comment: For `Ёё`, may we output codepoints U+00CB and U+00EB instead of U+0401 and U+0451?

Comment: @ETHproductions no, the text must be outputted exactly

Comment: Do we have to use Unicode? Or can we use an 8-bit Cyrillic encoding?

Comment: FFS I asked this a while ago and it got deletd

Comment: For users that can see it: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97469/print-the-russian-alphabet

Comment: Last time this was posted, it was output as a duplicate of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/97049/62131). Given how similar the solution is, I'm strongly tempted to close this as a duplicate, but I have a dupehammer so I can't do it with community review into the decision. Would someone else care to start the dupe vote?

Comment: Mendeleev, you say ‘it got deleted’, but the page itself says ‘This question was voluntarily removed by its author.’ What's going on here?

Answer (score 21):

## [Рапира](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapira) (Rapira), <s>172</s> 142 bytes

```
ВЫВОД: "АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczFEcIAAAXRVpiUQTc5cmPoILhDILgNLsHdaWF/RSGHvbzDRsxwKGJ6HhVcvz5OMGBQZo/NwYcjVU44nKlxwZJNnSsNbjS50@JBmycdXnR50@PjL74M@DGUxUhRxooxUZypEsyUZK4UC6VZKsNKWVzlWCvPRgW2KrJTyfC8Pw)

Just for fun, given the challenge. It may not be golfed; I'm not really familiar with the language.

Comment: @user202729 That's because it was a function definition that was never called, and there was a typo. It works now.

Answer (score 15):

## Mathematica, <s>43</s> 42 bytes

`Alphabet` is a built-in function.

-1 byte from Martin.

```
ToUpperCase@#<>#&/@Alphabet@"Russian"<>""&
```

This may not work on some older versions of Mathematica, but it does work on [Wolfram sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) and [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BasMwEETv@opFgdAG4/5AGlxKDz30kjYnY8hGXtUCeyWkdeN8vWs50F7nDW9mQOloQHEGZ/s8f/lTCBRfMVG12R8226fqpQ8dXkgqfRxTcsh6f9B6Oz/s1LuFK0HrIhnpbxCiY0mwCMF4FmIBb8HWDWAChCQL/y7g438Srq7vFSWDgcAJiIcTO@PbbGiphE@fFzr8ocxoCj7KOnCX5RDBup4Khdxmwvcba0loErjcII7MuX02KOdS7R6VeltVtRYaQimT6CIfbdRx5FovNfgDzfwL).

---

Another version without builtin `Alphabet` or `ToUpperCase`:

## Mathematica, <s>82</s> 66 bytes (64 chars)

```
Insert[FromCharacterCode@{#,#+32}&/@(1039+Range@32),"Ёё",6]<>""&
```

or

```
Insert[FromCharacterCode@{#,#+32}&/@1040~Range~1071,"Ёё",6]<>""&
```

Unfortunately Martin's trick (use `a<>b` instead of `{a,b}`) doesn't work here.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc3NasJAFIbh/VzF4QjiT7CJKRXFSIpYcFfcpllM05NJwMzI5PhTpIKX4J3pFaXBumhddfvB872F5IwKyXkiqzSo5roky9GLNcU0k1YmTHZqPijcN5xG1@9/NR/Cluf6w@5CakWh3287eD5eTug8xeMJYrNqdeB5WTNdn24INmTL3GjY5pxBKQuC90@mxKw1j6DTFkIF4j9Vz310D9fowXMH3l1ViFebaw7xTadRDAGgmO1Wpj7FtMc7RgfqPRaLtY4wkQw/a/zLqTunbk79cermqm8)

Comment: Of *course* `Alphabet` is a built-in. Freaking [goats](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/38183) is a built-in.

Comment: @Downvoters Well, don't downvote this just because it's over-upvoted. It's a completely valid answer, and not overly boring, eithre. I hate seeing my reputation being "fractional"...

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't downvote. There shouldn't be a punishment for knowing a built-in.

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
40r71s6j25Q+ȷỌżŒl$
```

A full program. Pretty similar in nature to an [existing answer by Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127683/53748), but I *think* it's different enough.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/EoMjcsNgsy8g0UPvE9oe7e47uOTopR@X/fwA)**

#### How?

```
40r71s6j25Q+ȷỌżŒl$  Main link: no arguments
40r71               inclusive range from 40 to 71: [40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71]
     s6             split into sixes: [[40,41,42,43,44,45],[46,47,48,49,50,51],[52,53,54,55,56,57],[58,59,60,61,62,63],[64,65,66,67,68,69],[70,71]]
       j25          join with 25s: [40,41,42,43,44,45,25,46,47,48,49,50,51,25,52,53,54,55,56,57,25,58,59,60,61,62,63,25,64,65,66,67,68,69,25,70,71]
          Q         de-duplicate: [40,41,42,43,44,45,25,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71]
            ȷ       literal 1000
           +        addition: [1040,1041,1042,1043,1044,1045,1025,1046,1047,1048,1049,1050,1051,1052,1053,1054,1055,1056,1057,1058,1059,1060,1061,1062,1063,1064,1065,1066,1067,1068,1069,1070,1071]
             Ọ      cast to characters: "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
                 $  last two links as a monad:
               Œl     lowercase: "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
              ż       zip: ["Аа","Бб","Вв","Гг","Дд","Ее","Ёё","Жж","Зз","Ии","Йй","Кк","Лл","Мм","Нн","Оо","Пп","Рр","Сс","Тт","Уу","Фф","Хх","Цц","Чч","Шш","Щщ","Ъъ","Ыы","Ьь","Ээ","Юю","Яя"]
                    implicit print: АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя
```

Comment: I think it's different enough too, not because of `+ȷ` but because of the `s6(...)Q` approach.

Comment: Thanks @EriktheOutgolfer - I created it, then saw yours and almost commented to give the improvement.

Comment: BTW I'm incorporating the improvement, but keeping my approach for 19 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## C#, Java, Javascript 137 bytes

Note: Java is only valid if you replace `=>` with `->`

```
s=>"АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя"
```

Ahhhh!!! Found a shorter way for

## C#, <strike>102</strike> 99 bytes

```
a=>string.Concat(new string[32].Select((x,i)=>(x=(char)(i+1040)+"")+x.ToLower())).Insert(12,"Ёё")
```

Shortened it by using a different approach

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/K@g4Faal2xTXFKUmZeuowCh7RTSgIIKtgr/E23tIEJ6zvl5yYklGnmp5VBF0cZGsXrBqTmpySUaGhU6mZq2dhoVthrJGYlFmhqZ2oYGJgaa2kpKmtoVeiH5PvnlqUUampqaep55xalFJRqGRjpKFxovTlTS/G/NFV6UWZKqAbJTA6hB0/o/AA)

Comment: What encoding is this? Pretty sure it's 138 bytes.

Comment: This is 138 bytes. Also, replace `()` with a single character to save a byte.

Comment: @Shaggy Sorry misread the TIO, question doesn't specify that unused parameters are allowed but I will edit them in

Comment: In UTF-8 this is 138 bytes, but 72 characters

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>75</s> <s>38</s> <s>32</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
;Bi";<=>?@," c+981 ®+v
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0JpIjs8PT4/QCwiIGMrOTgxIK4rdg==&input=)

- 1 byte saved thanks to ETHproductions.

---

### Explanation

```
;B        :The uppercase alphabet
i         :Prepend ...
";<=>?@," :  this string
c         :Map over the charcodes of each character in the string...
+981      :  and increment them by 981
®         :Map over each character in the string, replacing them with themselves...
+Zv       :   and their lowercase selfs
          :Implicit output of resulting string
```

---

### History

[75 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IihIKUkqSitLLEwtTRlpLk4vTzBQMVEyUjNTNFQ1VTZWN1c4WDlZOlo7WzxcXD1dPl4/X0BgQWFCYkNjRGRFZUZmR2ciY18rI2Qw&input=), [38 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0KuK1p2w3JmImYygiIgKyJbXHtcXHxdfV5+X39gIiBjXys5NzU=&input=), [32 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0KuK1p2w2kiOztbPFw9XT5eP19AYCx8IiBjXys5ODE=&input=), [24 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0JpIjs8PT4/QCwiIGNfKzk4McOuK1p2&input=)

Comment: I *think* this works: http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I2gwbyNrMl9kCu1VbXYpYw==&input=LVAKCg==

Comment: @obarakon; nice one. But `Ё` & `ё` are missing. Also, you can save a couple of bytes with multiline and small tweak: http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I2gwbyNrMl9kCu1VbXYpYw==&input=LVAKCg== EDIT: See you got those improvements already.

Comment: That's what I did in my edit :P And darn `Ёё`. You can do `i"Ёё"B` but that would cost too many bytes.

Comment: Adding `Ãi'ЁB` to the end of the first line would be a byte shorter: http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I2gwbyNrMl9kw2knXHUwNDAxQgrtVW12KWM=&input=LVAKCg==

Comment: I think you'd have to do `Ãi'Ё6`, but yeah good idea.

Comment: @obarakon, you should post yours as a separate answer when you've figured it out. Ping me in chat if you want to talk through it more.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
71r40s26j25+ȷṚỌżŒl$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//NzFyNDBzMjZqMjUryLfhuZrhu4zFvMWSbCT//w)

Thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for posting his [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127694/41024) (even though he outgolfs me) for -1 :)

Comment: Since Jelly's code page does not have the Cyrillic alphabet, don't you need to count the bytes in UTF-8? I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony The output codepage doesn't have to do with the code codepage.

Answer (score 5):

### PHP, <s>68</s> 66

```
for(;$i++<33;)echo$c=ڀ^"
".chr($i-7?16+$j++:1),mb_strtolower($c);
```

slight improvement over the previous attempt by xoring instead of appending.
`ڀ^"\n"` constructs the necessary `"\0xd0\128"` and xors in the lower 7 bit.

Comment: Cool 'for' loop. Never seen that in my life.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
X12ssmCM+B+1040d32U32"Ёё
```

```
                  U32     generate the range [0, 1, 2, ..., 30, 31]
     m         d          for each element in the range,
          +1040           add 1040, giving the uppercase cyrillic letter
        +B      32        bifurcate over adding 32, giving [upper, lower]
      CM                  convert each into a character
   ss                     join into a single string
X12                  "Ёё  insert this string at index 12
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=X12ssmCM%2BB%2B1040d32U32%22%D0%81%D1%91&debug=0).

Comment: Because the output is different.

Comment: @LeakyNun Ah, TIO seems to have mangled the encoding. It does work locally, however.

Comment: `Ñ` doesn't belong there...

Comment: @LeakyNun I've changed the link to the other online Pyth interpreter, which runs it correctly.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with `rB ... Z`: `X12ssmrBC+1040dZU32"Ёё`

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 106 bytes

```js
f=
_=>"АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ".replace(/./g,c=>c+c.toLowerCase())
console.log(f())
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
žv47ŸžB+çJ6т‚£'ЁýDløJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f8wNWFiMWX//8W@djQ3xbjFvkIrw6dKNtGC4oCawqMn0IHDvURsw7hK//8)

**Explanation**

```
žv47Ÿ                    # push range [16 ... 47]
     žB+                 # add 1024 to each
        çJ               # convert to a string of characters with those code points
          6т‚£           # split into 2 pieces, the first being 6 chars long
              'Ёý        # merge the 2 strings on "Ё"
                 Dlø     # zip with a lower case copy
                    J    # join to a string
```

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't even see you had an answer posted; let alone that there were 4 05AB1E answers already lol.

Comment: AND `l` WORKS ON RUSSIAN ALPHABETS?! WHAT.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Hehe, yeah. Pretty practical :P

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes = 18 bytes + 2 UTF-8 bytes

```
T„(GÇ«ŸçJ„ЁЖ6ǝDløJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5FHDPA33w@2HVh/dcXi5F5B3ofHCNLPjc11yDu/w@v8fAA)

---

Credit to Emigna for the `lowercase` trick and for `3°` isntead of `3Tm`.

---

## How?

```
T                  # Push 10.               | [10]
 „(G               # Push "(G"              | [10, "(G"]
    Ç              # Convert to ASCII.      | [10, [40, 71]]
     «             # Concatenate.           | [[1040, 1071]]
      Ÿ            # Range.                 | [[1040, ..., 1071]
       çJ          # Convert to char, join. | ["А..Я"]
         „ЁЖ       # Push "ЁЖ"              | ["А..Я", "ЁЖ"]
            6ǝ     # Replace "Ж" w/ "ЁЖ"    | ["А.Ё.Я"]
              Dl   # Duplicate, lowercase.  | ["А..Ё..Я", "а..ё..я"]
                øJ # Zip together and join. | ["АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя"]
```

---

Alternate 20 byte version (no UTF-8): `T„(GÇŸ„.Ç6ǝ˜«çJDløJ`

Even more random 20 byte nonsense: `T„(GÇŸ„.Ç6ǝ˜«vyçDlJ`

(The key takeaway is that I don't think I'm getting below 20 here).

Comment: @Emigna figures I missed the hard part of the challenge heh...

Comment: @Emigna none of my answers would be valid without you ._. lol.

Comment: Nice trick with `T` and `«`!

Comment: @Emigna took a minute, knew there was something I could to to make `40 79` not awful.

Comment: @ETHproductions the two alternate ones use no UTF-8.

Comment: Heads up: This is displaying as 18 bytes in the userscript's leaderboard.

Comment: @Shaggy wow, sorry it took so long to see this, next time you have permission to edit it for me.

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 58 bytes

```
"ABCDEF2GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`"{#Ϗ+..#Ёe#P:# |+}>&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fydHJ2cXVzcjdw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomJjYuPkGpWvl8v7aenvKFxlTlACtlhRrtWjs1h///AQ)

Woo!

### Explanation

Adds `Ϗ` (975) to each character in ABCDEF2GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
Then duplicates and adds space (32), unless the character is `Ё`, in which case it adds P (80)

Comment: Would it shave a byte to duplicate and test before adding `Ϗ`, since `Ё` is two bytes?  I'm assuming UTF-8 - is that what's here?

Comment: @TobySpeight no because we're checking if the original value plus `Ϗ` is `Ё`, and yes, Braingolf uses UTF-8

Comment: My thinking was if we test before adding `Ϗ`, then that's a test against `2` (1 byte) rather than against `Ё` (2 bytes).

Comment: @TobySpeight we have to duplicate before pushing the space or `P` though, otherwise it'll cost us a byte to swap the values

Comment: Ah, I see.  You already have my vote, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 93 bytes

```
s->"АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя"
```

Source file should be saved in `Windows-1251` encoding so the source makes for 71 bytes, plus flag to compiler `-encoding WINDOWS-1251` for 22 bytes more.

Comment: [Beaten to it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127680/58974)

Comment: @Shaggy Well, I would've posted an idea to use different encoding there as a comment, but that answer was intended for 3 languages, and the flag to the compiler is specific to Java, so I posted this as a separate answer.

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify the flag. Since Windows-1251 is the default charset on Russian Windows (and `javac` always uses the default charset by default). Just mention that and you're good with only 71 bytes. But my answer even beats that ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>69</s>  66 bytes

-3 bytes using the form (using `'%c'` to directly apply `chr()`) from [totallyhuman's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127719/53748), do go give some credit!

```python
v=32
while v:print('Ёё'*(v==26),end='%c%c'%(1072-v,1104-v));v-=1
```

A full program (two double-byte characters used, `Ё` and `ё`).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8zW2IirPCMzJ1WhzKqgKDOvREP9QuPFiepaGmW2tkZmmjqpeSm26qrJqsnqqhqGBuZGumU6hoYGJrplmprWZbq2hv//AwA)**

Comment: Heh... I thought my answer looked different enough until I just actually read your code and turns out I just reversed the order. >_>

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, <s>55</s> 47 bytes

*8 bytes saved thanks to @Zacharý*

```
⎕UCS 66⍴⍉2 33⍴1025+(14+⍳6),0,(20+⍳32),80,52+⍳26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE4BkqHOwgpnZo94tj3o7jRSMjYEsQwMjU20NQxPtR72bzTR1DHQ0jAxAbGMjTR0LAx1TIxDHyOz/fwA)

Comment: [`(,⍪,819⌶)⎕ucs¯6⌽1040+¯15,6⌽⍳32`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZv6jtgkGIBaQ1tB51LtKx8LQ8lHPNk2gUGly8aH1Zo969hoamBhoH1pvaKoD4j3q3Wxs9P8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>64</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
5ÝD1040+s1072+‚øžB>D80+‚«25ÝD1046+s1078+‚ø)˜çJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f9PBcF0MDEwPtYkMDcyPtRw2zDu84us/JzsXCAMQ5tNoIqsIMrMICokLz9JzDy73@/wcA)

Comment: You can save a byte by using `žB>` instead of `1025`

Comment: @Datboi True, but the 20 byte Jelly solution makes me sad.

Comment: @Okx there's a 22 byte 05AB1E solution ;).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 71 bytes

```
."Ёё    kdâ¿Ããä©ÃòçÅD´fjÃØÜr
ÔE®8CðÒº[£÷6ÓþC0"
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%22%D0%81%D1%91%01%09kd%C2%92%C3%A2%C2%BF%C3%83%C3%A3%C3%A4%C2%A9%C3%83%C3%B2%C3%A7%C2%93%C3%85D%01%C2%B4f%C2%8Fj%C3%83%C3%98%C3%9Cr%C2%96%0A%03%C3%94E%C2%AE%C2%888C%C3%B0%C3%92%C2%BA%5B%C2%A3%06%03%07%14%C3%B7%C2%9D%C2%8E6%C3%93%C3%BEC%C2%840%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>96</s> 92 bytes

- *@Mayube suggested this to save 2 bytes, and succeeded to golf it down by 1 byte by declaring `chr(i)`.*
- *@Rod golfed 4 bytes by removing `chr(i)`.*

```python
for i in[chr(ord(i)+975)for i in"ABCDEF2GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`"]:print(end=i+i.lower())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITMvOjmjSCO/KEUjU1Pb0txUEyau5Ojk7OLqZuTu4enl7ePr5x8QGBQcEhoWHhEZFR0TExsXn6AUa1VQlJlXopGal2KbqZ2pl5Nfnlqkoan5/z8A)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>104</s> 99 bytes

Any suggestions are welcome.

```python
for i in"АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ":print(end=i+i.lower())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoJQGIDRrYgjJXDSLGg3Gf4Q98pFiIbtINPKSns/NEu38u3odk68SCKthtZOtXHEEeWyImVNRs6GJVt2FOw5cKSk4sSZC1du3Hnw5MWbmoYPLV9@dPTuKDaiEi9Uk7EMJJjpeWg837f2Dw)

Comment: With `map(chr,range(65,91))` you have "ABC..Z" in 21 byte instead of 29. //  So we have: `i in map(chr,range(65,91))+"[\\]^_'"` (37byte)  vs `i in"ABCDEF2GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`"` (40byte).

Comment: @P.Siehr note the problematic `Ё` and hence the `2` placed between `F` and `G`, which mapping `chr` over `range` does not yield (see my Python answer for a different workaround).

Comment: @JonathanAllan I didn't notice that - sorry. But here is another solution for your Python3 version: `print(*[i+i.lower() for i in"АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"])`, if whitespaces are ok in the output.  [TIO](https://tio.run/##BcFJDoIwGIDRqzSsABM3Hse4xPgnpm0aEuOSG@AMzjOKClf5blTfs9N0ZHTPe@tEp2Hcl450x2aSuDBSQ@OUKNEBOTPmLFiyImPNhoKSLTv2HDhy4syFKzfuPHhS8eJNzYcvPxraYBB5/wc)  (-1 Byte)

Comment: @P.Siehr that is 98 bytes due to Python using UTF-8 encoding. White space is only allowed after the text in this challenge too (usually Kolmogorov-complexity challenges only allow an optional trailing newline).

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>94 93</strike> 90 bytes

```cs
_=>{var r="";for(var i='А';i<='Я';)r+=""+i+(char)(i+32)+(i++=='Е'?"Ёё":"");return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xasMwEIZ3P8WhxRJKMqRbFDlDoFMLhQ4dg1Dl5MCR4KQEivHQN0iHPEdexXkiR04hXfoP993d/x@cjVMbyA2QZRsTI7xR2JLZF@OmvddRMZmEFo4BP@HVoOfiYf2FRr1/xeT2s@eDt8uYCP12Ar@soAZdDBtdtUdDQJoxVQfi44C67E@lwmXmpVSCZHYlSm53hgRH@TQXMkPqHDiXK9Z/X3/YgjGhyKUDeSDVDar475V18DE0bvZBmNwLesdrng@FeoS7e9cNNw)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 29 bytes

```
1040ÐU5+ŸžB>X6+D25+Ÿ)˜çDl)ø˜J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0MDE4PCEUFPtozuO7nOyizDTdjECcTRPzzm83CVH8/CO03O8/v8HAA)

Uses the lowercase / uppercase trick from the python answer

#### Explanation

```
1040ÐU5+ŸžB>X6+D25+Ÿ)˜çDl)ø˜J
1040                          # Push 1040
    Ð                         # Triplicate top of stack
     U                        # Saves top of stack in X
      5+Ÿ                     # Push range [1040, ..., 1045]
         žB>                  # Push 1025
            X                 # Push X (1040)
             6+D25+Ÿ          # Push range [1046, ..., 1071]
                    )         # Wrap stack to array
                     ˜        # Flatten array
                      ç       # Convert to character
                       Dl     # Create a lowercase copy
                         )ø   # Zip both together
                           ˜J # Flatten and join
                              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.0, 77 Bytes

```php
for($t=IntlChar;$i++<33;)echo$c=$t::chr($i-7?1040+$j++:1025),$t::tolower($c);
```

[IntlChar Class](http://php.net/manual/de/class.intlchar.php)

## PHP, 136 Bytes

```php
for(;$i<mb_strlen($r=АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ);)echo$m=mb_substr($r,$i++,1),mb_strtolower($m);
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4111a0343b19b6b93f81ed6eb93ba76a60e5cdd)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 136 bytes

```php
<?=АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHFDUIBAETBiqgACLUQQsIJKAF3d3d3d2nhbTGcPzNel9cwLDYrOXbk2VPgQJEjJU6UOeNXngoXqlypcaPOnQYPmjxp8aLNmw4funzpyUdffgYKMFSQkUKMFWaiCFNFmSnGXHEWSrBUkpVSrJVmowxbZc2G8XN7TA67w@X8Aw)

Comment: Currently at [68 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127709/29637) :)

Comment: @Christoph nice idea

Answer (score 1):

## Bash+coreutils, <s>101</s> <s>100</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s> 74 bytes

```sh
printf %b\\n \\u04{51,{3,4}{{0..9},{a..f}}}|sort|sed 's/./\u&&/'|tr -d \\n
```

This requires a UTF-8 locale such as `ru_RU.utf8` (English UTF-8 locales also sort correctly).  I've not added any score for this, as per the [consensus on meta](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7881).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 bytes

```python
for i in range(32):print(end='%c%c'%(i+1040,i+1072)+'Ёё'*(i==5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9hI06qgKDOvRCM1L8VWXTVZNVldVSNT29DAxEAHRJkbaWqrX2i8OFFdSyPT1tZUU/P/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>59 56 55 54</s> 51 bytes

```ruby
32.times{|x|$><<((x==6?"Ёё":"")<<x+1040<<x+1072)}
```

Thanks to manatwork for at least 4 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/39hIryQzN7W4uqaiRsXOxkZDo8LW1sxe6ULjxYlKVkpKmjY2FdqGBiYGENrcSLP2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

22 bytes of code (encoded in UTF-8), +2 for the `-P` flag.

```
#h0o#k2_dÃi'Ё6
®+Zv
```

Similar to the below method, except instead of pairing two arrays, I join each capital letter with itself, lower-cased.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XznDIF852yg@5XBzpvqFRjOuQ@u0o8r@/9cNAAA)

### 26 byte solution:

I had some help from @Shaggy, who discovered that `Ё` wasn't in the `[1040...1071]` char range.

```
#h0o#k2_dÃi'Ё6
íUmv)c
```

### Explanation:

```
#h0o#k2_dÃi'Ё6
íUmv)c
                   // Implicit U =
   o               //   Range      
#h0                //     [1040...
    #k2            //             1071]
       _           //   Map; At each char,
         d         //     Get the char-code
          Ã        //   End mapping;
           i'Ё6    //   Insert "Ё" into index 6;
í                  // U paired with:
 Um                //   U, where each char:
   v               //   Converted to lowercase
     c             // Flatten
-P                 // Join into a string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XznDIF852yg@5XBzpvqFRjOuw2tDc8s0k///1w0AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 60 bytes

```ruby
u=?Џ
l=?Я
32.times{$><<u.next!+l.next!+(l==?е?"Ёё":"")}
```

(Just a demonstration of [`String#next!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-next-21), the multibyte literals ruin the 55 characters score.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ ruby -e 'u=?Џ;l=?Я;32.times{$><<u.next!+l.next!+(l==?е?"Ёё":"")}'
АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9TW/kI/Vw6QXM9lbKRXkpmbWlytYmdjU6qXl1pRoqidA6U1cmyBirbaK11ovDhRyUpJSbP2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 26 bytes

```
ＦＥ⮌⪫⪪…⮌…γ⁷²¦³²Ｌαi℅⁺℅ιφ⁺↥ιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwEER/JfS0gXqpBw8ecxPFovgBS9y2C0sStrHg18cED53DDLx3GL@g@ohSyhTVwA0TPGgjXQkukQM8k3AG9/VCbom73Mncm9NgbW@OQ60rhTkvgA103LVx9QJ9JoVRPivc9c0BBbiqydaYUTnkv3ylROqxHjTN1p5LKYdNfg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＥ⮌⪫⪪…⮌…γ⁷²¦³²Ｌαi
```

Take the first 72 printable ASCII characters, reverse them, then take the first 32 of those (this is actually shorter than slicing and reversing, although slicing didn't exist at original time of posting anyway), then insert the `i` after the `N`, then reverse again. The resulting characters happen to have ASCII codes that are exactly 1000 less than the desired Russian lower case letters.

```
  ℅⁺℅ιφ
```

Calculate the Russian lower case letter by adding the predefined variable `φ` (`f`) which has the value 1000.

```
    ⁺↥ιι
```

Print the upper and lower case letters. (`«↥ιι` would probably also work.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>91</s> 88 bytes

```java
()->{String s="";for(char i=0,u=1039,l=1071;i<33;)s=i++==6?s+"Ёё":s+ ++u+ ++l;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBbT9RgEH3fXzH2qU2hgWyCwVL8AUZ92EfjQ13a5VtLW/t9H4aQTQBRuSty98ZF8H5Hbir6F878orVlN/GFh5lJzpyZc2bq/rDfmaRBXB@43Uz1rUhUqRr5UtJVX8Q0WiJqo1L5Ki/DiRigobxnVlQm4tqNm@RnNWmdUYnq@T5HKxE5oY6rSiSxU9FpGokg62sN9FNIXtO0OvtHWwBJzzDcMMnM6qCfkfC6OrTX3VXu7YjycrHbFX3lsmtJT9i25/VclraBcV40LkmbbFsXKXKzQOksJuk2moUNt3TmpjIiVTDkJFo5aS6lotiMg7vU0jVDpxYo07KsNluEZF4w8BhfsYhveILvWMI@lvEDKzgoNLGKQ6zhCOs4xgZO8BQ/8Qy/8By/8QKneIk/2MRfbPEYtnkcOzyBV3wPuzyJPb6P1/wAb/gh3vIU3vE03vMMPvAsPvIcPvE8PvMCvvAjwwnuaD@S/y2233vuSca1RNH1K0Z@R8FolIpoNP8B)

Encoded in Windows-1251. Must use a default Russian Windows installation.

Comment: You're Missing `Ёё`

Comment: @Mayube Fixed, for a great amount of extra bytes :(

Comment: You can do `i++` and change the code accordingly to save 2 bytes: `()->{String s="";for(char i=0,u=1040,l=1072;i<33;i++)s=i==5?s+"Ёё":s+ ++u+ ++l;return s;}`

Comment: Indeed, `i` is only a counter. I intended to use it otherwise at first.

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 31 bytes

```
gr'v6R,' &w'ѷ~-.O' +'С'ёSOk@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/z@9SL3MLEhHXUGtXP3i9jpdPX91BW31CwvVL04M9s92@P8fAA)

#### Explanation

```
g       Read the first character of the source code. That's g itself, with
        code point 103, so this pushes 103. The exact value is irrelevant
        but we need something greater than 31.
r       Range. Turns 103 into 0, 1, 2, ..., 103.
'v      Push 118.
6R,     Move it down the stack by 6 elements, so the top of the stack is
        ..., 96, 97, 118, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103.
' &w    Push the current IP address to the return address stack 32 times, 
        which will cause the following part to be executed 33 times.

  'ѷ~-    Subtract the value on top of the stack from 1143, which gives the
          33 code points of the upper case letters.
  .O      Print a copy of this value as a character.
  ' +     Add 32. This turns the upper case letters in the main range to their
          lower case counterparts. However, this doesn't work for Ё/ё, where
          we obtain C instead.
  'C'ёS   Replace the divisor 1057 with 1105. The only value among the 33 which
          is divisible by 1057 is 1057 (C) itself, so that it simply gets turned into
          1105 (ё). 
  O       Output the lower case character.

k       Jump back to the w as long as there's a copy on the return address stack.
@       Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 33 bytes

```
/ZАе"е"ёяSr@
\"'Я"rЁа""o/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/6sKEC1uVgOjixIv9wUUOXDFK6hfWKxVdaLywQUkpX///fwA)

My other Alice solution was entirely in Cardinal mode, this one is entirely in Ordinal mode. It's conceptually much simpler, but unfortunately two byte longer.

#### Explanation

Ignoring the Ordinal template, the program is entirely linear:

```
"АЯ"r"ая"rZ'е"еЁё"So@
```

Alice does have a built-in to convert between lower and upper case, but unfortunately in the Ruby interpreter it only works on ASCII letters, so we still have to get both ranges separately.

```
"АЯ"r     Push "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ".
"ая"r     Push "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя".
Z         Zip. Interleave the two strings.
'е"еЁё"S  Replace "е" with "еЁё".
o@        Print the result and terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 79 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(x=1039;++i<33;){f="%c%c";f=i==6?f f:f;printf f,i+x,i+32+x,1025,1105}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686Lb9Io8LW0MDY0lpbO9PG2NhaszrNVkk1WTVZyTrNNtPW1sw@TSHNKs26oCgzrwTI1MnUrgBiYyMgZWhgZKpjaGhgWlv7/z8A)

This works on TIO, not sure if it's dependent on installed char-set.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 80 bytes

```
import Data.Char;f=putStr$(\x->[x,toLower x])=<<['А'..'Е']++'Ё':['Ж'..'Я']
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 37 bytes

```
print map{chr.chr($_+32)}(1040..1071)
```

It's annoying that Perl's character autoincrement only works for the Latin alphabet.  I could save so many characters if it worked outside that range.